# Good way to make \textcircled numbers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, circles

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`circledsteps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circledsteps)

I'm trying to make some good-looking numbers in a circle, using the simple command:

```
\textcircled{1}
```

However, the circle is misaligned vertically with the number, and look a bit sloppy:

[image]

Any suggestions how can I adjust the vertical alignment so that the numbers look more centered w.r.t to the circles? Or, if that's not an option, what other ways to achieve the same results are possible?

I will use those only for numbers, and in very few places, so manual adjustment per glyph is an option.

I'm using `pdfLaTeX` with Computer Modern, if that matters.

Comment: Got two good answers here, for less than 30 minutes (you guys are fast!). I'll probably make a community wiki answer summarizing all options one of these days, maybe some other solutions will come along in the meantime.

Comment: I'm sleep-deprived, that's why!

Comment: What package provides `\textcircled`?

Comment: @Matthew: It seems to be built-in with LaTeX. Works out of the box.

Comment: You could use Unicode. U+2460-2473 for 1 to 20, U+24EA for 0, U+3251-325F for 21-35, and U+32B1-32BF for 36-50.

Comment: Related Question: [Circle around a number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294572/circle-around-a-number/).

Comment: For a correct copy and paste see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70899/9075

Comment: Had a similar problem, here is how I solved it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512845/properly-align-superimposed-symbols-used-as-custom-bullet-of-an-itemize-environm

Comment: Anyone has the solution for the inside of the circle is filled (black) and the number is in a different color (white)?

Comment: As of 2022-09-26, the standard `\textcircled{0}` … `\textcircled{9}` in Computer Modern are better than in the OP. Namely, running pdflatex on https://pastebin.com/raw/fwY6wFz9 yields https://i.imgur.com/nDZZ14q.png .  Here, most circles don't touch the digits, whereas in the OP, all circles visibly touch the digits.

Comment: @MartinTapankov Could we kindly ask you to please provide us with the LaTeX code that gave you the output you posted? As you see from [my comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers#comment1640997_7032), I get a slightly [different output](https://i.imgur.com/nDZZ14q.png) than you do, perhaps because [my input](https://pastebin.com/raw/fwY6wFz9) is different.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Depending on the version of the font or the TeX distribution, the output may indeed be different, and the exact output shown by the OP may not be reproducible with a current TeX distribution. However, a current TeX distribution will still produce an output where the numbers are not optimally positioned in the circle, at least in my opinion. And that is the main point of the OP's question: How to get nicer circled numbers.

Comment: @JasperHabicht It's clear what you mean, but still, the question lacks the source code, which implies that it's unknown how the output was produced, strictly speaking. You could refer to my input https://pastebin.com/raw/fwY6wFz9 in [my comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers?noredirect=1#comment1640997_7032) or use some other input and get, presumably, some other another output. We don't wish to compare apples and (not even pears, no) unknown fruits.

Comment: @JasperHabicht And of course you're right that the TeX distribution better be known, too. It's difficult to judge whether your claim “a current TeX distribution will still produce an output where the numbers are not optimally positioned in the circle” if “produce from what” is not given. Lots of folks, including me and you, apparently made a clever guess, but, strictly speaking, it's still no more than a guess.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I was pleasantly surprised how many people decided to give it a try, and a lot of interesting solutions popped out. As per tradition, this answer will be community wiki and  will summarize and compare all suggested solutions.

---

I hereby suggest three different evaluation criteria, each graded from 1 to 5:

- **Simplicity**. This is a measure how easy it is to use the proposed solution. Points deducted for using additional packages, or defining anything other than a simple convenience macro.
- **Flexibility**. This primarily includes how easy is to use this in other contexts, in this case different frame shapes, sizes and thicknesses.
- **Accuracy**. Simply put, how aesthetically pleasing the solution looks, particularly how well the glyph is centered in the circlce, and how it fits surrounding free-running text.

Here we go:

1. The `raisebox` solution.

   Thanks to *Jimi Oke* for the fast fingers. This came in first, and is the one that I particularly like for the application I had in mind. It comes as easy as:

   ```
   \raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {8}}}
   ```

   Nothing more than that. On the simplicity front, it doesn't get any better than this. Solid **5/5**, as no extra packages are needed, and the unwieldy definition can be trivially abstracted in a one-liner `\def`.

   Flexibiltiy-wise, this solution rates quite low, as you have no control on the circle size or parameters (I'm sure that some TeX hackers would prove me wrong, but for the love of *$DEITY*, spare us such abominations). **2/5** is well-deserved here. {1}

   The accuracy issue is subjective as always, but you'd need to play around with the vertical distances to get it Just Right (tm) for the typeface you have selected. **2/5**.
2. The `ding`-y solution.

   This came in from *TH.* that suggests using some predefined symbol glyphs. The omniscient symbols-a4 document says that The One True Way to do it is to use:

   ```
   \usepackage{pifont}

   \ding{172}--\ding{181} % seriffed fonts
   \ding{192}--\ding{201} % sans-seriffed fonts
   ```

   Or even the Go board nomenclature:

   ```
   \usepackage{igo}
   \whitestone{1}--\whitestone{99}
   ```

   On the simplicity side, this rates at **4.5/5**, although I'm reluctant to give it a straigt 5 due to the extra packages involved.

   This is not flexible at all. If you don't like the glyphs, you're on your own. **1/5**.

   The glyphs themselves are well-designed, as one should expect, and the numbers are visually well-aligned with the circles. Although if you have a a typeface with a distinct style, the numbers font might not mesh well with the text.
3. The obligatory `tikz` solution.

   Ahh, there's always that, isn't it. This is due to *Stefan Kottwitz*.

   ```
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
       \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
   \begin{document}
   Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} end.
   \end{document}
   ```

   Personally, I'm not into `tikz` (I know, I should learn it one of these days), so going with this would be a one-off use of the package for me, which I'd like to avoid. I can't give more than **2/5** here, but the `tikz` fanboiz (and galz!) should bump this up all the way to **4/5**.

   As far as flexibility is concerned: this is the real deal. Stefan demonstrated even how to use the circled symbols with enumerated lists, of all things. Different frame shapes are certainly possible, with varying degree of fit around the glyph. Indisputable **5/5**.

   Baseline alignment is top-notch without playing around with some manual adjustments, which is quite nice. The spacing around the symbol looks all right, although in free-running text the circle should preferably have a tighter fit around the number, which can be achieved by playing around with the `inner sep` parameter in the command definition. **5/5** here.
4. `pict2e`/`picture` solution

   A late addition by *Herbert* proposes uses some basic primitives from the `picture` and `pict2e` packages. Here goes:

   ```
   \usepackage{pict2e,picture}
   \newsavebox\CBox
   \newlength\CLength
   \def\Circled#1{\sbox\CBox{#1}%
     \ifdim\wd\CBox>\ht\CBox \CLength=\wd\CBox\else\CLength=\ht\CBox\fi
       \makebox[1.5\CLength]{\makebox(0,1.5\CLength){\put(0,0){\circle{1.5\CLength}}}%
       \makebox(0,1.5\CLength){\put(-.5\wd\CBox,0){#1}}}}
   ```

   On the simplicity front, this doesn't rate too well. It looks a bit convoluted, although definitely understandable after studying it, and uses two additional packages. **2/5** is a reasonable score here.

   Flexibility is not quite built-in, but is certainly possible. The circle radius can be adjusted, by modifying the `1.5` factor, and the baseline adjustment can be played with. **3.5/5**.

   As it stands in this definition, the baseline of the surrounding text is tangent to the circle instead of being aligned with the circled number base. This might be desirable in some circumstances, but the numbers look a bit out of place in this way. Better results are achievable with some additional calculations when placing the boxes, and a **3.5/5** is given here to reflect this potential.
5. The other obligatory `tikz` solution

   *Matthew Leingang* and *morbusg* tried their hand in this, and while their efforts are certainly appreciated, I feel Stefan's solution is simpler. I am grateful for the effort (and your humbleness), and I upvoted both your answers.

Final score:

- **Simplicity** : `raisebox`
- **Flexibility** : `tikz`
- **Accuracy**: tied between `tikz` and `ding`

Overall: `tikz`, without hesitation (acclamation from the public, hats thrown, handkerchiefs waved and all that).

Finally, some test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture} % picture 
\usepackage{tikz}   % tikz
\usepackage{pifont} % ding

% Picture solution
\newsavebox\CBox
\newlength\CLength
\def\numcircledpict#1{\sbox\CBox{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd\CBox>\ht\CBox \CLength=\wd\CBox\else\CLength=\ht\CBox\fi
    \makebox[1.5\CLength]{\makebox(0,1.5\CLength){\put(0,0){\circle{1.5\CLength}}}%
    \makebox(0,1.5\CLength){\put(-.5\wd\CBox,0){#1}}}}

% TikZ solution
\newcommand*\numcircledtikz[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt] (char) {#1};}} 

% Modified \textcircled solution
\newcommand*\numcircledmod[1]{\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {#1}}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        Original & Lorem \textcircled{1} ipsum \textcircled{2} dolor \\
        Modified & Lorem \numcircledmod{1} ipsum \numcircledmod{2} dolor\\
        TikZ & Lorem \numcircledtikz{1} ipsum \numcircledtikz{2} dolor\\
        Picture & Lorem \numcircledpict{1} ipsum \numcircledpict{2} dolor\\
        Ding serif & Lorem \ding{172} ipsum \ding{173} dolor\\
        Ding sans & Lorem \ding{192} ipsum \ding{193} dolor\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

{1} If somebody *does* decide to write such a thing, let me know and I will include it in this answer at no additional cost, but be advised that the post will be subsequently marked `\textcircled{18+}` to protect the faint of heart.

Comment: excellent summary, well done! Posts such as this makes this Site worthwhile.

Comment: @Yiannis It's been some time since I posted the question, but I only found time just now to polish the summary. I hope it will be of use to people with the same problem.

Comment: You say, "The spacing around the symbol looks all right, although in free-running text the circle should preferably have a tighter fit around the number." This is easily fixed by changing `inner sep=2pt` to `inner sep=1pt` in the `\circled` command definition.

Comment: @Matt: Sure -- my intention here was to point out an aesthetic issue, but I guess I wasn't quite clear on that. The info about what needs to be changed is now mentioned in the post. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinTapankov Thank you for this overview. However, it seems that neither tikz nor raisebox work for text within a caption of a table, and since I need a character rather than a digit, pifont will not work either...

Comment: @MartinTapankov The problem is solved with raisebox provided every call is preceded with \protect.

Comment: maybe it worth mentioning that if you are going to use TikZ new command inside a caption you should put after `\protect` command. it took me while to figure this out!

Comment: ...the only problem with the `tikz` solution is that it can't be used *inside* a `tikzpicture`, as for example in a node text or a label...

Comment: `pifont` based `ding` does not match the font

Answer (score 324):

Here's a TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} end.
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's just a node. TikZ options are used to align the base line, to adjust the size and to get the circle shape. You're free to choose further options regarding size or circle thickness (option `thick`). There's more: for example you could even name the nodes by another argument to connect them by arrows later.

If one like to use it for an enumerated list, for example, it's easy but has to be protected:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet example! I have had problems in the past using TikZ examples inline but now I see that is solved by `baseline=(char.base)`. Cool.

Comment: @Stefan: perhaps you should replace `\newcommand` by `\DeclareRobustCommand`, like that the `\protect` is not needed any more, which is more user friendly.

Comment: @Philippe: Good idea! One has to be careful though - by `\DeclareRobustCommand` we could accidentally overwrite an existing command. `\newcommand` would issue an error in contrary to `\DeclareRobustCommand`. But I guess, who uses `\DeclareRobustCommand` knows that. :)

Comment: Then one should use \newcommand to declare an empty command fist and then use \DeclareRobustCommand. That way, an existing command will issue an error.

Comment: I guess there is a way, but where would I give it the command to use a specific font family for the numbers?

Comment: Small, kludgy tweak if you decide to use \circled for smileys, but the text rotation messes with your baseline: `\newcommand*\circledsmiley[1]{\tikz[baseline=0,yshift=1mm]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,rotate=270] (char)
  {\footnotesize{}\texttt{#1}};
}}`

Comment: Nice solution, I want to do the same thing but with a dashed-circle, would you help me?

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez Sure! Comments are not the best for code discussions. Perhaps post a new question, or let's talk at the [LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/) where I post daily.

Comment: To whom it may concern: `minimum width` can be used to force the circles to have the same dimensions. (@cartonn Probably  `\protect` will help you (or `DeclareRobustCommand`, see comments above).)

Comment: Hi Stefan Kottwitz!

  Example: `\underset{\Rightarrow}{\circled{1}}` the output of `\circled{1}` is not scaled. Can we fix this?

Comment: @AndreaLeo Define `\newcommand*\subcircled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,scale=0.6] (char) {#1};}}` and use that one. `scale` could also made to be an optional parameter for `circled`.

Comment: It seems that you cannot use this in caption? 
Can this be changed?

Comment: @Stefan Is it possible to turn your answer into tikz-style of which can be customized with respect to its fill color, draw color, text color, circle size, etc.?

Comment: This is nice, but the problem is that it can't be used inside a `\tikzpicture` --- like, for example, a node text or a label. Is there any solution for an "universal" nice circled numbers? For reference, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496348/alternative-to-using-nested-tikz-in-reference-able-markers

Comment: How can I have inverted color? That is, the number font is white but the circle is filled up with black. Edit: Never mind, solved it.

Comment: Exceptionally brilliant!

Comment: How can i make \circled{10} as big as \circled{9}

Answer (score 43):

The quickest fix would be to use the `\raisebox` command. I've played around with it a bit, and it seems lowering the text by 0.9pt puts the figure approximately in the center:

```
\textcircled{\raisebox{-0.9pt}{8}}
```

You could play around with it to get the absolute center but it's definitely between 0.9 and 1pt. I got the idea [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/lmodern/textcircled.pdf). It seems the `\textcircled` command works best for text! But, anyway, this should solve your problem.

Comment: That's going to change the baseline of the numbers which might not be desirable. But perhaps with an outer `\raisebox` to raise the whole circled number, baselines could be maintained.

Comment: Mais oui! I should have thought of this myself. Thanks! I'll wait a bit for some more suggestions, before I mark this as accepted.

Comment: @TH. True, but that doesn't matter for me -- the numbers do not appear in the free running text, but are rather headers for table columns or used for labelling.

Comment: But, actually, the `\textcircled` output already has a lower baseline with or without the `\raisebox`. So, if the author prefers it all flush, then he should go for `pifont`. With an outer `\raisebox`, the maximum is a 0.5pt raise, which gets the circle back to its original position, which is not flush with the text, though. Raising everything beyond 0.5pt begins to shift the number, not the circle, negating initial efforts. Thus, if the author wants a good `\textcircled`, then here's one: `\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {8}}  }`. This is actually pretty good.

Comment: @Martin: you might also get a TikZ suggestion. ;-)

Comment: @Stefan I'd be direly concerned that something's wrong on TeX.SE if I don't :-)

Comment: @Martin: done :-) if you like it you might consider to add a {tikz-pgf} tag and a note to your question, that TikZ would be acceptable. The tag would make it visible for TikZ friends.

Answer (score 33):

#### this answer has been converted in a package on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/circledsteps

The answers here are all nice, and especially the `tikz` one is greatly configurable. But it has a problem: you can't use it inside other `tikzpicture`s safely. So I merged a couple of things and implemented this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers
%
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/inner ysep/.initial=4pt,
    /csteps/inner xsep/.initial=4pt,
    /csteps/inner color/.initial=red,
    /csteps/outer color/.initial=blue,
}
\newsavebox\csteps@CBox
\newlength\csteps@XLength \newlength\csteps@YLength \newlength\csteps@YDepth \newlength\csteps@tmplen
\def\csteps@CircledParam#1#2{\sbox\csteps@CBox{#2}%
    \csteps@XLength=\wd\csteps@CBox\advance\csteps@XLength by\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner xsep}\relax
    \csteps@tmplen=\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner ysep}\relax
    \csteps@YDepth=\dp\csteps@CBox\advance\csteps@YDepth by 0.5\csteps@tmplen\relax
    \csteps@YLength=\ht\csteps@CBox\advance\csteps@YLength by\dp\csteps@CBox\advance\csteps@YLength by\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner ysep}\relax
    \typeout{DBG:#2\space X\space\the\csteps@XLength\space Y:\the\csteps@YLength\space D:\the\csteps@YDepth}%
    \raisebox{-#1\csteps@YDepth}{%
    \ifdim\csteps@XLength>\csteps@YLength
    \makebox[\csteps@XLength]{% X bigger than Y
        \makebox(0,\csteps@YLength){%
            \color{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/outer color}}\put(0,0){\oval(\csteps@XLength,\csteps@YLength)}%
        }%
    \makebox(0,\csteps@YLength){%
        \put(-.5\wd\csteps@CBox,0){\textcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner color}}{#2}}%
    }}%
    \else
    \makebox[\csteps@YLength]{%
        \makebox(0,\csteps@YLength){%
            \color{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/outer color}}\put(0,0){\circle{\csteps@YLength}}%
        }%
    \makebox(0,\csteps@YLength){%
        \put(-.5\wd\csteps@CBox,0){\textcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner color}}{#2}}%
     }}%
    \fi
    }%
}
\def\Circled#1{\csteps@CircledParam{1}{#1}}
\def\CircledTop#1{\csteps@CircledParam{0}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  This is normal text \Circled{1} is on the baseline, \CircledTop{2} is on top.
  \par\bigskip
  This is more evident if you have descendent, like p:\Circled{p} and \CircledTop{p}.
  \par\bigskip
  For big horizontal things it becomes oval: \Circled{200} or \CircledTop{199}.
  \par\bigskip
  Inside \texttt{tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, rotate=30, text width=3cm, transform shape]
      \node [draw,color=green!50!black]{text \Circled{1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par\bigskip
  \tikzset{/csteps/inner ysep=10pt}
  \tikzset{/csteps/inner xsep=10pt}
  More space: \Circled{1}  \Circled{2} \Circled{p} \Circled{200} \Circled{199}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of use]

Comment: Looks great! (+1)

Comment: The above CircledSteps code works perfectly as a MWE, but when I try to insert the code into my project I get the following error: "! LaTeX Error: Command \csteps@CBox already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual." Any thoughts on what is happening would be greatly appreciated!    Note:The same error occurs when the extra comma (,) is removed from the end of the line "/csteps/outer color/.initial=blue," ... Thanks!

Comment: Re CircledSteps code: I also double-checked to make sure there were no other instances of \csteps@CBox already defined ... Thanks!

Comment: Please, try to recreate the problem with a minimal example (a complete one) and I'll try to help. You can post a question here and ping me in a comment or open an issue on GitHub https://github.com/Rmano/circledsteps/issues. I can't do much without an example...

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the automatic switch to oval for "big horizontal things"? Something as small as the letter `M` leads to the circle becoming oval, which makes the package unusable for my case

Comment: @ScumCoder, I'll have a look. But it would be better if you post a question with a minimal example.

Comment: @ScumCoder, ok, I saw it. Try this: `\newcommand\Bigcircled[1]{\Circled{\strut #1}}` and use `\Bigcircled`. Now the circle is the size of a `\strut`, and I think all the letters fit.

Comment: @Rmano thanks a lot for the answer. The strut indeed keeps the circle from becoming oval, but it also makes it huge - still unusable for me. Anyway, I just used the `pict2e`/`picture` solution (#4 from the community wiki) and now I'm happy.

Comment: @ScumCoder If you want the minimum size to keep an "M" with a circle, you can use `\newlength{\mwidth}\setlength{\mwidth}{\widthof{M}}\newcommand\Bigcircled[1]{\Circled{\vrule width 0pt height \the\mwidth #1}}` or similar (need the `calc` package)

Answer (score 25):

[morbusg already mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7046/4012) that some fonts have encircled numbers as **Unicode glyphs** and showed how to embed them directly. Some fonts provide a **more user-friendly interface** for accessing the numbers, e.g. Linux Libertine and Junicode. Obviously, this means that we’re deviating from your requirement to use Computer Modern. The advantage of these Unicode numbers presumably is that they were crafted by a font designer, so there shouldn’t be any need for fine-tuning.

Here’s a simple proof-of-concept (You also need to have the `junicode` package installed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\libertineGlyph{uni2460} \libertineGlyph{uni24F5} \libertineGlyph{uni2776}

{\fontspec[Ligatures=Discretionary]{Junicode}[1] [[1]] <1>}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

These methods are described in the respective documentations.

Here’s an even more comfortable way of accessing these sets of numbers. The doubly circled numbers are (per Unicode) available from 1 to 10, the others from 0 to 20.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{pgf} % for the calculation
% \libcirc and \libcircblk display their '0' if the parameter is out of range
\newcommand{\libcirc}[1]{\pgfmathparse{
    ifthenelse(#1 > 0 && #1 < 21, Hex(9311+#1), Hex(9450)
    }\libertineGlyph{uni\pgfmathresult}}
\newcommand{\libcircdbl}[1]{\pgfmathparse{Hex(9460+#1)}\libertineGlyph{uni\pgfmathresult}}
\newcommand{\libcircblk}[1]{\pgfmathparse{
    ifthenelse(#1 > 0 && #1 < 11, Hex(10101+#1),
        ifthenelse(#1 > 10 && #1 < 21, Hex(9450-10+#1),
            Hex(9471)
        )
    )
    }\libertineGlyph{uni\pgfmathresult}}

\newcommand{\juncirc}[1]{{\fontspec[Ligatures=Discretionary]{Junicode}[#1]}}
\newcommand{\juncircdbl}[1]{{\fontspec[Ligatures=Discretionary]{Junicode}[[#1]]}}
\newcommand{\juncircblk}[1]{{\fontspec[Ligatures=Discretionary]{Junicode}<#1>}}

\usepackage{pgffor} % just for the demo loop
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the demo
\begin{document}
\section{Linux Libertine}
\foreach \x in {0,...,20} {\libcirc{\x} }

\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {\libcircdbl{\x} }

\foreach \x in {0,...,20} {\libcircblk{\x} }

\section{\fontspec{Junicode}Junicode}
\foreach \x in {0,...,20} {\juncirc{\x} }

\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {\juncircdbl{\x} }

\foreach \x in {0,...,20} {\juncircblk{\x} }
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I think this does not work with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @moose Yes .. I have to check if the first code bit works with the current `libertine` at all (but then pdfLaTeX should be fine), the second bit is XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX only, I should put that in the answer as well.

Answer (score 24):

Even easier:

```
\textcircled{\small{2}}
```

or

```
{\large \textcircled{\small 2}}
```

or

```
{\Large \textcircled{\normalsize 2}}
```

[ed. Segletes, providing MWE & image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\large\protect\textcircled{\small\arabic*}]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\end{enumerate}

    \textcircled{\small{2}}

or

    {\large \textcircled{\small 2}} 

or

    {\Large \textcircled{\normalsize 2}}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX rendering of the above .tex file]

Comment: This *might* work when the circle is not surrounded by text, and the font size of the number is not an issue -- but I'd rather use one of the other solutions instead.

Comment: Can we invert the colours inside the circle?

Comment: I like the simplicity of this zero-dependency answer. I had luck with `\textcircled{\tiny{M}}`.

Comment: This solution is better suited for text. `\textcircled{\small{M}}` and `\textcircled{\tiny{M}}` both work better than `\Circled{M}` as `\Circled{M}` will make an oblong circle around the 'M'.

Comment: I've also found `{\small{\textcircled{\tiny{M}}}}` useful.

Comment: `\footnotesize` looks better than both `\small` and `\tiny` in this case, imo.

Answer (score 20):

From symbols.pdf, it looks like `pifont` can do what you want with `\ding{172}` through `\ding{181}` or `\ding{192}` through `\ding{201}`.

Or the `igo` package with `\whitestone{1}` through `\whitestone{99}`, although that's meant for typesetting Go boards.

It sounds like the solution has been found, but here's a simple comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\def\X#1{%
        #1%
        \textcircled{#1}%
        \raisebox{.9pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt}{#1}}}%
        \ding{\numexpr171+#1\relax}%
}
\begin{document}
\X0\X1\X2\X3\X4\X5\X6\X7\X8\X9
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution. However, the pifonts are rather squished, compared to the `\textcircled` output. The pro, though, is the pifonts are flush with the text, which may be a good thing for the author.

Comment: @TH: Nice. What does the textcomp package do?

Comment: @Jimi: I thought it was required for `\textcircled`. I was incorrect. (I was looking at Table 17 of Symbols.pdf and it notes that `textcomp` is required for `\newtie`, but I wasn't reading carefully enough.) I've updated the code.

Comment: @PatrickT Thanks for the image. It's a good addition.

Answer (score 20):

PGF is overkill for this one application, but if you already have it loaded, you can use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\pgftextcircled}[1]{
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
    \dimen0\wd0%
    \divide\dimen0 by 2%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]%
        \useasboundingbox (-\the\dimen0,0pt) rectangle (\the\dimen0,1pt);
        \node[circle,draw,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0.1ex] (a) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\pangram}{\noindent{The \textcircled{0} quick \textcircled{1} brown \textcircled{2} fox \textcircled{3} jumps \textcircled{4} over \textcircled{5} the \textcircled{6} lazy \textcircled{7} dog.}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\pangram
\bigskip

\let\textcircled=\pgftextcircled
\pangram
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: snippet output]

As you can see there's some extra space around the circles compared to `\textcircled` but it's not bad.

pre-post edit: I see Stefan and morbusg have beat me to the punch.  Oh well.

Comment: I think an external process is indeed overkill for something that can be done inside LaTeX. You can just as simply construct it as \newcommand{\Ring}[1]{\raisebox{-1pt}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}{\small#1}\\[-11.5pt]\BigCircle\end{tabular}}}. Auto-adjustment of the dimensions is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Comment: Peter, what external process?

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae: I think Peter is referring to the fact that `tikz` uses a bunch of `\special` commands added after TeX processes the input.  So it's “external” to the normal TeX digestion system.

Answer (score 17):

The [`mathdesign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign) package defines `\figurecircled` which has better spacing for numbers than `\textcircled` does.

The mathdesign package is incompatible with `amsfonts` and `amssymb` but if you're using a mathdesign font anyway, that's not a problem.

Comment: This answer got voted down? Could whoever did this explain why they think this is a bad solution to the problem?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I did get an error with a simple test file.  Can you provide a MWE?  My error message: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \figurecircled ->\MDB-cmd \figurecircled         \MDB\figurecircled l.14 ...footnote{of the emergency} $\figurecircled                                                {1}$
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: In the middle of page 6 of mathdesign-doc.pdf from 2013-08-29, we see “\figurecircled{1} gives 1 (better than \textcircled{1}: ①).” Something is wrong.

Answer (score 14):

@Stefan's answer is good, however, I improved his answer.

Firstly, if `\circled{1}` and `\circled{10}` are placed together, the two circles will not be the same size, so I added an optional parameter to the `\circled` command. The optional parameter was regraded as a placeholder to make sure that these circles appear in the same size.

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](https://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/005yyi5Jjw1enghxoen2bj30jo05kjsd.jpg))</sub>

Additionally, since I'd used `\ifblank`, which is provided by package `etoolbox`, to check if the optional parameter was provided, I used `\robustify` to make the command robust. This bypassed the disadvantage of using `\DeclearRobustCommand`, mentioned by @Stefan in a comment of his answer. Thus, the `\protact` is no longer needed.

---

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\circled}[2][]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape = circle, draw, inner sep = 1pt]
    (char) {\phantom{\ifblank{#1}{#2}{#1}}};%
    \node at (char.center) {\makebox[0pt][c]{#2}};}}
\robustify{\circled}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}\rlap{\rule{.7\linewidth}{.4pt}}%
The original version: \circled{1} and \circled{10}.

\mbox{}\rlap{\rule{.7\linewidth}{.4pt}}%
The improved version: \circled[10]{1} and \circled[10]{10}.

\newcommand{\dcircled}[1]{\circled[00]{#1}}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\dcircled{\arabic*}, noitemsep]
\item I
\item am
\item happy
\item to
\item join
\item with
\item you
\item today
\item in
\item what
\item will
\item go
\item down
\item in
\item history
\item as
\item the
\item greatest
\item demonstration
\item for
\item freedom
\item in
\item the
\item history
\item of
\item our
\item nation.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](https://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/005yyi5Jjw1engi79j2u1j30ge0rsq5a.jpg))</sub>

Comment: you know the option `minimum size` for nodes?

Comment: @percusse Sorry, but I don't understand you.

Comment: You can define a minimum size for circle nodes without a box or phantom with uniform size.

Comment: @percusse That's a good suggestion, however, I don't think you understand the idea in my post. I designed this optional parameter to uniform the size of the circles, since different sized circles that are aligned together will give a unfriendly looking.

Answer (score 11):

With Plain (stumbled upon this by chance and remembered this question):

```
\def\circled#1{{\ooalign{\hfil\lower.1ex\hbox{#1}\hfil\crcr\Orb}}}
$\circled1 \circled2 \circled3 \ldots \circled9 \quad \circled{23}$
\bye
```

[image: circlednums]

With XeTeX:

```
\font\circled="Arial Unicode MS"
{\circled ➀} Didn't occur to me {\circled ➄} earlier that some fonts have {\circled ➇} these.
\bye
```

Or maybe with TikZ:

```
\input tikz
baseline ain't so pretty \par
baseline ain't so pretty \par
baseline \tikz \node[circle,draw] {2}; ain't \par
so pretty \tikz[baseline] \node[circle,draw] {2}; baseline \par
ain't so pretty baseline \par
ain't \tikz[inner sep=1pt,baseline=-.75ex] \node[circle,draw] {2}; so pretty \par
baseline \tikz[inner sep=2pt,baseline=-.75ex] \node[circle,draw] {2}; ain't so \par
pretty baseline ain't so \par
pretty \tikz[inner sep=.25ex,baseline=-.75ex] \node[circle,draw] {2}; baseline \par
... actually, now it sorta is \par
baseline ain't so pretty \par
baseline ain't so pretty
\bye
```

[image]

Darn, Stefan beat me to it with a nicer one.

Answer (score 9):

with the default picture commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}
\newsavebox\CBox
\newlength\CLength
\def\Circled#1{\sbox\CBox{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd\CBox>\ht\CBox \CLength=\wd\CBox\else\CLength=\ht\CBox\fi
    \makebox[1.2\CLength]{\makebox(0,1.2\CLength){\put(0,0){\circle{1.2\CLength}}}%
    \makebox(0,1.2\CLength){\put(-.5\wd\CBox,0){#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\Huge
foo
\Circled{1}
\Circled{2}
\Circled{ABC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `\pdfliteral` solution.  It only works for single numbers.

```
\def\circled#1{%
  #1%
  \pdfliteral{
    q .5 w
    10 0 0 10 -2.5 3.5 cm .05 w .5 0 m
    .5 .276 .276 .5 0 .5 c -.276 .5 -.5 .276 -.5 0 c
    -.5 -.276 -.276 -.5 0 -.5 c .276 -.5 .5 -.276 .5 0 c h
    S Q
  }%
}
\circled{1} a
\circled{2} b
\circled{3} c
\circled{10}
\bye
```

> [image]

Comment: Why the coordinate transformations ?

Comment: @percusse Actually, I just copied code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220024/creating-shapes-like-circle-rotated-squares-and-triangle-without-tikz) and modified it a little.  If you can provide any resources to learn more about PDF coding, I would be really happy.

Comment: It is actually PostScript but PDF also supports many graphics objects. So it's a bit cumbersome to understand the set of all operators supported in PDF. But at least to start reading this code you can use the reference guide https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf. Also in the ISO spec (table 59 in http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html ) you can recognize the TikZ operators mapped to frontend ;). The initial problem to grasp is setting up the bounding box the rest is usual PS notation.

Comment: @percusse Does your comment imply that the above could also work for latex+dvips compilation into a .ps file?

Answer (score 5):

Using *pifont* package and symbols from `\ding{172}` to `\ding{211}` you easily have very excellent circled numbers, but if you want circled numbers bigger than 10 we have a problem. As showed by other stackexchange users here, we can solve the problem if numbers are not too big, but things became hard (complex LaTeX codes) and we can have problems if we are writing inside a text (if the circle became big, LaTeX can be forced to enlarge space between lines, or maybe to overlap circle upon adjacent upper and lower lines): things are a bit simpler if we only want circled number in a itemize list. This lack in flexibility could be in some case bothersome. A reasonable solution seems to use the *tcolorbox* package: after attempts I found that we simply have to add in preamble this

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox} \newcommand{\ciao}[1]{{\setlength\fboxrule{0pt}\fbox{\tcbox[colframe=black,colback=white,shrink tight,boxrule=0.5pt,extrude by=1mm]{\small #1}}}}
```

and call in the document the command \ciao when we want a "circled" number (example: \ciao{12} will "circle" the number 12). By the way, the use of fbox in the preamble line is important because without it, rounded box could protrude out of the line on the left or on the right when they are at the margin of the line: this would be very unaesthetic.

Resuming, I see in this solution 3 pros and 1 cons:

- **pros**: simple code, good working inside a text too, flexibility (big numbers too & in case we can easily play with borders or colors: see 0.5pt or black&white in the preamble line).
- **cons**: we don't have circles but rounded box, but I find this a reasonable compromise.

An example of application of this method is

```
Quel ramo del lago di Como \ciao{1}, che volge a mezzogiorno, tra due catene \ciao{20} non interrotte di monti, tutto a seni e a golfi, a seconda dello sporgere e del rientrare di quelli, vien, quasi a un tratto, a restringersi, e a prender corso \ciao{252} e figura di fiume, tra un promontorio a destra, e un'ampia costiera dall'altra parte; \ciao{3432} e il ponte che ivi congiunge le due rive, par che renda ancor più sensibile all'occhio questa trasformazione, e segni il punto in cui il lago cessa, e l'Adda ricomincia, per ripigliar poi nome di lago dove le rive, allontanandosi di nuovo, lascian l'acqua distendersi e rallentarsi in nuovi golfi e in nuovi seni.
```

that gives

[image]

please note that numbers doesn't protrude and that the space between lines is always the same: no matter if we have a number or not. In short, this almost circled numbers works very well even if they are inside a text.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circledtext is another option for you, it's great!

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circledtext}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10,100,999}
  {
    \circledtext{\x}\,
  }

  \circledtextset{boxcolor=cyan,boxtype=ox,charf=\Large,boxfill = red!20}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10,100,999}
  {
    \circledtext{\x}\,
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pifont}
%%% grab https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/magic
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{magic}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{magic}{m}{n}{<-> magic}{}
%\usepackage{relsize}%%% if you wish to adapt to the size of the main text, downscaling by a factor of 2.5 seems just about right.
\begin{document}
%\textsmaller[2.5]{%
  \Pisymbol{magic}{48}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{49}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{50}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{51}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{52}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{53}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{54}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{55}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{56}
  \Pisymbol{magic}{57}
%}
\end{document}
```

[image: magic standalone output]

The borders parts of the circles are slightly cut; otherwise, everything is fine.

If you go with `article` instead of `standalone`, you won't even notice:

[image: magic article output]

NewTX also provides us with the symbols, but the bounding boxes are even more wrong:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
\textcircled{0}\textcircled{1}\textcircled{2}\textcircled{3}\textcircled{4}\textcircled{5}\textcircled{6}\textcircled{7}\textcircled{8}\textcircled{9}
\end{document}
```

[image: NewTX standalone]

With `article` instead of `standalone`, all seems fine again:

[image: NewTX article]

Answer (score 0):

In MathJax, you can use the [`enclose`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/enclose.html) macro from the `enclose` extension. Here's some sample code and its output.

```
$$\enclose{circle}{1} \enclose{circle}{2} \enclose{circle}{3}$$
```

[image]

Although the OP is using pdfLaTeX, I figure I won't be the only person to ask the same question about MathJax.