# Circle around symbol

Tags: circles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)

Is there an easy way to get an circle around  a symbol in math mode?

Comment: You'll find _a lot_ of information here: [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/1235)

Comment: Should this be closed as duplicate?

Comment: Is the linked question not mainly/only about text mode? Are the solution there also suitable for the math mode?

Comment: @user4011: Have a look the linked question and its answers and tell us if these work for you or not. If they do we close this question as duplicate just to keep the site tidy.

Comment: @user4011: Thanks, please add a '@MartinScharrer' to this comments so I get notified. Thanks.