# Package for coin symbols (heads, tails)

Tags: symbols, packages

Does anyone know if there is a package that includes symbols for coins? I'm typesetting a solution I wrote for a probability problem dealing with coin flips and I'm trying to include some visual aids that would hopefully have coins showing heads and tails, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: A symbol for coins? What about images of real coins? Have you checked [`symbols-a4.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) already?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yeah I looked through the symbols-a4 pdf already and didn't find anything (although there's a lot in there so I might have missed something).

Comment: You could take pictures from http://www.random.org/coins/ ;)

Comment: @knut That's great! Never seen that site before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no such package.

You may create you own coin symbol. All you need is a [circled text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15334/getting-numbers-to-appear-in-circles) and a symbol.

I made an example with 1$ and an eagle on the other side (I know, the [original US-$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_coin_%28United_States%29) has another look ;) ):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{phaistos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\coin[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\coin{1\$}

\coin{\PHeagle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a more realistic look, I would recommend to take pictures of real coins.
[random.org](http://www.random.org/coins/) has a nice collection of pictures.