# How to box every digit of an integer ?

Tags: formatting

What is the LaTeX command for boxing a number like for example 123 as:

---

### |1|2|3|

I have seen it in a book but can't find it anywhere in TeXnicCenter, which I use.

Comment: Do you want to place every number in a box, or in other words for every number to have a border? Roughly like the output of `\(\fbox{1} \fbox{2} \fbox{3}\)`? It would help if you supplied an image of what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know any packages that provide macros for this, but it can be done easy enough:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand*{\boxednumber}[1]{%
    \expandafter\readdigit\the\numexpr#1\relax\relax
}
\newcommand*{\readdigit}[1]{%
    \ifx\relax#1\else
        \boxeddigit{#1}%
        \expandafter\readdigit
    \fi
}
% Format macro used for every digit, adjust to your liking:
\newcommand*{\boxeddigit}[1]{\fbox{#1}\hspace{-\fboxrule}}

\begin{document}

\boxednumber{123}

\boxednumber{\thepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) for some tips about the formatting of the digits. However it's actual for circles not boxes.

Comment: I tried to avoid any `@` code here to not confuse LaTeX beginners. I like to use `\expandafer .. \the\numexpr` because it allows to provide the number also as counter value or macro.

Comment: Note: The left line of the frames look funny, but it actually just the usual zooming/anti-aliasing issue of Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\def\BoxNumbers#1{|\BoxNumbers@i#1|\@nil}
\def\BoxNumbers@i#1#2|\@nil{%
  #1|\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\BoxNumbers@i#2|\@nil\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\BoxNumbers{123} \BoxNumbers{123789}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the theme by Martin:

```
\makeatletter
\def\boxnumber#1{\mbox{\toks@={\@gobble}\@boxnumber#1\relax\the\toks@}}
\def\@boxnumber#1{\ifx#1\relax % end
  \else
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@\@numbersep#1}%
    \expandafter\@boxnumber
  \fi}
\def\@numbersep{\kern1pt\vrule\kern1pt}
\makeatother
```

Here `\boxnumber{123}` will give (approximately)

> 1|2|3