# Is it possible to know and use the number of items of one list?

Tags: lists, environments

The following code gives one way to use circled numbers in one list. For the moment this solution uses one parameter given by the user which is the "width" of the total number of items of the list.

```
% Sources :
%   1) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-pgftextcircled-numbers
%   2) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33738/customize-diameter-of-a-circle-around-numbers/33744#33744

\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \newbox\nodebox
    \newcommand\pgftextcircled[2][0]{%
        \ifnum#1=0%
            \setbox\nodebox\hbox{#2}%
        \else%
            \setbox\nodebox\hbox{0}\wd\nodebox\dimexpr\wd\nodebox*#1\relax
        \fi
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]%
            \node[
                draw,circle,
                outer sep=0pt,
                inner sep=0.5pt
            ](a){\hbox to \wd\nodebox{\hss#2\hss}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect{\pgftextcircled[1]{\arabic*}}]
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect{\pgftextcircled[2]{\arabic*}}]
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
    \item Item n°9
    \item Item n°10
    \item Item n°11
    \item Item n°12
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Could it be possible to define one environment `enumerateCircle` which knows automatically the length of the list so as to use the following syntax ?

```
\begin{enumerateCircle}
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
\end{enumerateCircle}

\begin{enumerateCircle}
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
    \item Item n°9
    \item Item n°10
    \item Item n°11
    \item Item n°12
\end{enumerateCircle}
```

Comment: You could write the width to the `.aux` file and reuse it in the next run.

Comment: I'm not one LaTeX expert... How can I do to store this information in the `.aux` file and how can I reuse it ?

Comment: Yeah, I can't see a way of doing this in one run. Otherwise \value{enumi} is the value of the counter to use I think.

Comment: If several compilations are needed, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile the environment just to get the total number of items; this is a job for **environ**, with a redefinition of `\pgftextcircled` that takes as optional argument what size you want to encompass:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{enumitem,environ}
    \usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\nodebox
\newcommand\pgftextcircled[2][0]{%
  \sbox\nodebox{#1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]
    \node[
          draw,circle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          inner sep=0.5pt
         ](a){\hbox to \wd\nodebox{\hss#2\hss}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{enumerateCircle}
  {\setbox0=\vbox{
              \enumerate
                \BODY
                \global\chardef\enCir@final\value{\@enumctr}%
              \endenumerate}%
   \enumerate[label={\pgftextcircled[\number\enCir@final]{\arabic*}}]
     \BODY
   \endenumerate}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerateCircle}
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
\end{enumerateCircle}

\begin{enumerateCircle}
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
    \item Item n°9
    \item Item n°10
    \item Item n°11
    \item Item n°12
\end{enumerateCircle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this shorter code even if it seems a little slower than the preceding one.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, it is slower because it has to typeset the environment twice. But it's this way or adding a self-generated `\label` command in order to use the information at the next run.

Answer (score 2):

This shold be what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcount\item@cnt
\newcommand*\circle@arg[1]{%
    \tikzpicture[baseline=(a.base)]%
        \node[draw,circle,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0.5pt](a){\hbox to\max@wd{\hss#1\hss}};
    \endtikzpicture}

\long\def\get@body#1\end{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\collected@body\expandafter{\collected@body#1}\find@end}

\newcommand\find@end[1]{%
    \def\temp@name{#1}%
    \ifx\temp@name\name@env
        \count@item
        \setbox\z@\hbox{\item@number}\edef\max@wd{\the\wd\z@}%
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circle@arg{\arabic*}]
            \collected@body
        \end{enumerate}
    \else
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\collected@body\expandafter{\collected@body\end{#1}}%
        \expandafter\get@body
    \fi}

\newenvironment{enumcircle}
    {\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter\name@env\expandafter{\@currenvir}%
    \let\collected@body\@empty\get@body}
    \relax

\long\def\count@item@i#1\item{\expandafter\ifx\@car#1\@nil\count@item\else\advance\item@cnt\@ne\expandafter\item\fi}

\long\def\count@item{%
    \begingroup
        \let\item\count@item@i
        \collected@body\item\count@item\item
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\item@number\expandafter{\number\item@cnt}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumcircle}
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
\end{enumcircle}

\begin{enumcircle}
    \item Item n°1
    \item Item n°2
    \item Item n°3
    \item Item n°4
    \item Item n°5
    \item Item n°6
    \item Item n°7
    \item Item n°8
    \item Item n°9
    \item Item n°10
    \item Item n°11
    \item Item n°12
\end{enumcircle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution seems to be a litlle quicker than the following one but the code just after seems to be simpler to understand (I can't tkae time for analyse it for the moment).