# Stepslist: "Step k of n"

Tags: macros, environments, lists, counters

I am trying to come up with a new enumerated list environment "stepslist" such that the items are marked with "Step k of n", where n is the total number of items in one stepslist environment, and k is the kth item in it. Thus e.g. the code

```
\begin{stepslist}

\item A

\item B

\item C

\end{stepslist}
```

ought to render as:

> Step 1 of 3: A
>
> Step 2 of 3: B
>
> Step 3 of 3: C

and

```
\begin{stepslist}

\item A

\item B

\item C

\item D

\end{stepslist}
```

ought to render as:

> Step 1 of 4: A
>
> Step 2 of 4: B
>
> Step 3 of 4: C
>
> Step 4 of 4: D

I don't want to define the variable n myself; I want its value to be determined automatically by the macro. Conversations with GPT4 suggest a "two-pass approach" (which makes sense, since as I understand it `LaTeX` does not know at the beginning of a list environment how many items there are in it).

I am unaware if this can even be done, but if it can then I would appreciate a method that would work in Overleaf.

Comment: The [`etaremune` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/etaremune) solves this by writing a line per list to the aux file (i.e. the two-pass approach). Similar to the answers of [Q33748](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33748) one might typeset the list twice, once just for counting the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a label which counts the items:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{enumitem} % 
\newlist{stepslist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[stepslist,1]{label={Step \arabic* of \ref{steplist:\themylistcnt}:},ref=\arabic{stepslisti}}

\newcounter{mylistcnt} % for a unique label
\AddToHook{env/stepslist/begin}{\stepcounter{mylistcnt}}
\AddToHook{env/stepslist/end}{\label{steplist:\themylistcnt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{stepslist}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\end{stepslist}


\begin{stepslist}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{stepslist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. May I ask a followup question? First, I am using hyperref also, so to not generate links I replaced your \ref with \ref*. Second, in my document the indentation of the stepslist items are way off the margin on the left. I can fix this by adding the option "left=0pt" inside \setlist, but then Overleaf is giving yellow errors, e.g. "Reference `steplist:0' on page 0 undefined on input line 66.". Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: no don't ask follow up question in comments, that pings only me. Ask a new question (and with a proper example).

Comment: Thanks, I had meant to only ping you. I don't think the followup question has independent interest; it's about a certain implementation of your code (an implementation I explicitly state in my question as what interests me). I can indeed provide a proper example if you are willing to humor me further.