# Using circled numbers for answer choices in exam document class

Tags: numbering, exam

I'm using the `exam` document class for an exam with a multiple choice section. To match the appearance of the scantron form, I'd like to use circled numbers in the `choices` and `oneparchoices` environments. I've got it working for the `choices` environment, but it's not working for the `oneparchoices` environment.  Below is a minimal working example. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pifont}
\renewcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice}
\renewcommand\choiceshook{
  \addtocounter{choice}{191} 
}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\ding{\arabic{choice}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question With the choices environment this
\begin{choices}
    \choice  does
    \CorrectChoice  work
    \choice nicely 
\end{choices}

\question With the oneparchoices environment this
    \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice does 
    \CorrectChoice not      
    \choice work 
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a slightly modified version of circled numbering presented in [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers), here an alternative using [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to circle the numbers, rather than [`pifont`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont). The macro `\circled` encircles its argument with a `1pt` separation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}% http://ctan.org/pkg/exam
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand\choicelabel{\circled{\thechoice}}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\arabic{choice}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question With the \texttt{choices} environment this
\begin{choices}
    \choice  does
    \CorrectChoice  work
    \choice nicely 
\end{choices}

\question With the \texttt{oneparchoices} environment this
    \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice does 
    \CorrectChoice work      
    \choice nicely
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The advantage here is that it allows for selection beyond 9 options. However, I'm not sure whether the scantron is limited to only 9 selections (1 through 9).

Comment: Thanks - I like this alternative also because the choices are more readable.

Answer (score 5):

The `oneparchoices` environment resets the `choice` counter to 0. Quick patch:

```
\usepackage{pifont,etoolbox}
\renewcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice}
\renewcommand\choiceshook{
  \addtocounter{choice}{191} 
}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\ding{\arabic{choice}}}
\patchcmd{\oneparchoices}{0}{191}{}{}
```

Thus, also the `oneparchoices` environment will start from 191 like `choices`. Unfortunately there's no `\oneparchoiceshook`, so a different path must be followed.