# Enumerated list with blue circles and number inside it

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am creating a manual for an application and I would like to provide step by step directions of the application. For the step numbers, I would like to use big, blue circles with white numbers in it. Thus I was thinking if I can modify the bullet style, I would be able to achieve such list. I read few similar questions and it looks like it will have to use the `enumitem` package and the likes. Probably, there would be a new command for a big circle. I just don't know how to pull everything together.

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: How about http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34735/using-circled-numbers-for-answer-choices-in-exam-document-class ?

Comment: cool! i followed that thread and bumped into this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers  It shows how to create a circled number for a enumerated list. But now I will have to figure out tikz so that I can increase the circle size and fill it with color

Comment: When you're posting your next question, please show what you've already figured out, even if it is only basic usage of `enumitem`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) for your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item Step one
\item Step two
\item Step three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

To increase the circle size, play with the `inner sep` parameter (the border between the number and the circle). To change the color, play with the `fill` parameter.

If you wish to change the text color, you can use the `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\color{red}\arabic*}]
\item Step one
\item Step two
\item Step three
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image: red text?!]

Comment: thank you, Raphink, that's exactly what I am trying to do. Is there a parameter for text color as well?

Comment: Updated with text color.

Comment: <pre>\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle, draw,inner sep=11pt, fill=NavyBlue] (char) {#1};}}</pre> when I increase the circle size, the longer bulleted text creates extra space between lines. Would it be possible for to wrap text around the bullet circle

Comment: @karlos: Use backticks to highlight code in comments.

Comment: What happens when you use the pair `\label{list::item}` in the list and `\ref{list::item}` in the tex?

Answer (score 15):

Without loading tikz and default LaTeX macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\kern-2.5em%
  \put(0,4){\color{blue}\circle*{18}}\put(0,4){\circle{16}}%
  \put(-3,0){\color{white}\bfseries\large#1}~~}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item Step one
\item Step two
\item Step three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to further add to the top casted vote, if you want to not all the time set the text color you can also set the text color in the newcommand directly that way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt,text=red] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item Step one
\item Step two
\item Step three
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```