# How to "bubble in"/color fill an item counter ((A),(B),(C),...) in an enumerated list

Tags: lists, color, enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to make an answer explanation guide for a test where the correct answer is "bubbled in".

I've tried using the enumitem package and tikz as shown in this post ([Enumerated list with blue circles and number inside it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50446/enumerated-list-with-blue-circles-and-number-inside-it)), but it's messing up the default spacing and the counters of the other answer choices. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\Alph{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Answer A
\item[label=\circled{(\Alph*)}] Answer B
\item Answer C
\item Answer D
\item Answer E
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Ultimately what I want is something like this:

[image]

A transparent fill color would be nice. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to specify:

```
[label=\circled{(\Alph*)}]
```

but only:

```
[\circled{\Alph{enumi}}]
```

Moreover, it is also needed to advance the counter.

Therefore:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%        
        \node[circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt,opacity=0.5,text opacity=1] (char) {#1};}}

\def\cnt{\stepcounter{enumi}\Alph{enumi}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\Alph{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Answer A
\item Answer B
\item[\circled{\cnt}] Answer C
\item Answer D
\item Answer E
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A different approach. The main problem with this solution is that the placement of the circle is too "manual", and different fonts would require a new manual adjust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\newcommand\correct{%
  \tikz[overlay]\fill[fill=green!50!black, opacity=.2] (-3ex,.6ex) circle (2ex);%
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\Alph{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Answer A
  \item\correct Answer B
  \item Answer C
  \item Answer D
  \item Answer E
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You can play with `\labelsep` to get the the right placement with less of trial-end-error.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, defining a dedicated command `\citem` and using the features provided by `enumitem` (instead of manually redefining `\labelenumi`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%        
        \node[circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt,opacity=0.5,text opacity=1] (char) {#1};}}

\newcommand\citem{%
  \stepcounter{enumi}\item[\circled{\Alph{enumi}}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item Answer A
\item Answer B
\citem Answer C
\item Answer D
\item Answer E
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]