# color fill an item of an enumerated list

Tags: lists, enumerate

I've recently seen [How to "bubble in"/color fill an item counter ((A),(B),(C),...) in an enumerated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99096/how-to-bubble-in-color-fill-an-item-counter-a-b-c-in-an-enumerated) and I just wondered: what if I'd like to enumerate my list with the arabic numbers, i.e. 1,2,3 etc? What would be the code?

Comment: `\begin{enumerate} \item whatever \end{enumerate}` ?  (With `enumitem` if something more fancy is needed.)

Comment: ok but I think that this kind of code was used there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace all occurences of `\Alph` by `\arabic` in [How to "bubble in"/color fill an item counter ((A),(B),(C),...) in an enumerated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99096/how-to-bubble-in-color-fill-an-item-counter-a-b-c-in-an-enumerated):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%        
        \node[circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt,opacity=0.5,text opacity=1] (char) {#1};}}

\def\cnt{\stepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\arabic{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Answer A
\item Answer B
\item[\circled{\cnt}] Answer C
\item Answer D
\item Answer E
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]