# How can I create a new label for enumitem with tikz?

Tags: enumitem

## Question

How can I create a new label for list items in the enumitem environment with tikz that include a variable (a counter in this case)?

### Problem

Code does not compile.
Runaway argument?....

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\redcircle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
    \node[shape=circle,fill=red,text=white] at (0,0) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\redcircle{\arabic*.}]
        \item Test
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably need to put `\protect` before applying the new style.

Comment: See [Enumerated list with blue circles and number inside it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50446/5764) - use `\protect\redcircle`.

Comment: @Werner +1 Thanks! This other question clearly demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.