# How can i create an automatic numbering with a black colored box around each number?

Tags: numbering

I want to create an automatic numbering with a black colored box around each number .I have searched a lot but not able to find a suitable package .
please help me. Thank you
[image: Exactly like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50446/203621

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion based on an adapted version of [ℝaphink's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50452/134144)  and the use of the `tasks` package for the horizontal lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\boxednumber[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=rectangle,fill=black] (char) {\color{white}#1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label=(\Alph*), label-width=2em}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\boxednumber{\arabic*}]
  \item \textbf{What is the value of...} 
       \begin{tasks}(2)
         \task $-\dfrac{4}{5}$ but not $\dfrac{4}{5}$
         \task $-\dfrac{4}{5}$ but not $\dfrac{4}{5}$
         \task $-\dfrac{4}{5}$ but not $\dfrac{4}{5}$
         \task $-\dfrac{4}{5}$ but not $\dfrac{4}{5}$
       \end{tasks}
  \item \textbf{Two isosceles triangles...}
       \begin{tasks}(4)
         \task 25:35
         \task 25:35
         \task 25:35
         \task 25:35
       \end{tasks}
  \item \textbf{In an Arithmetic sequence}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the result ?

Comment: @AndréC: I have added an image.