# How can I run this code in documentclass{book}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, tikz-styles

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\bpebble[3]{%
\tikz{
\node[inner sep=0pt] 
 (image) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};%
\node[inner sep=0pt] 
 at (image.center) {#3};%
 }
}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\bpebble{height=2ex}{papiro}{\insertenumlabel}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\bpebble{height=1.8ex}{bricks}{\insertsubenumlabel}}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{\bpebble{height=1.6ex}{scroll}{\insertsubsubenumlabel}}

  \setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{enumerate subitem}{fg=white} 
 \setbeamercolor*{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=black} 

 \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{enumerate}
\item Third.
\end{enumerate}
\item Third.
\item Fourth.
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I adjust this code for a vertical enumerate in documentclass{book}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557403/how-can-i-adjust-this-code-for-a-vertical-enumerate-in-documentclassbook)

Comment: Please describe your problem clearer next time. For example, "I have this style of enumerate in beamer (code with companion image), how can I achieve similar style in document class book?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following example. I don't have required image files, hence dummy image `example-image.pdf` from [`mwe`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package is used.

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\bpebble[3]{%
  \tikz{
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (image) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (image.center) {#3};
  }%
}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{
  label=\protect\bpebble{height=2ex}{example-image}{\arabic*}
}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{
  label=\protect\bpebble{height=1.8ex}{example-image}{\arabic*}
}
\setlist[enumerate, 3]{
  label=\protect\bpebble{height=1.6ex}{example-image}{\arabic*}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First.
    \item Second.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First.
      \item Second.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Third.
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Third.
  \item Fourth.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]