# Customized items : how to fit them vertically?

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I tried to customize some items and the customized items are, of course, aligned with the line. But, in the case where, for instance, I use a circled number, I want to make the item move a little bit down so the number still be aligned with the line :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{pifont}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[{\Large \ding{182}}] Toto
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

I failed to find a command making this possible, is it possible to do so, or do you see a better way to achieve this purpose ?

Comment: What about a `tikz`-based approach as for example shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50452/134144?

Comment: @leandriis Yes, that's neat ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily obtain what you want with the `circledsteps` package, which relies on tikz:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\Circled[fill color=SlateBlue, outer color=SlateBlue, inner color=Coral]{\arabic*}}, font=\large\bfseries]
\item Toto
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can lower the glyphs:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newenvironment{dingenumerate}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\largeding*,ref=\arabic*]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\largeding}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.4ex}{\Large\ding{\numexpr181+\value{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{dingenumerate}
\item Toto
\item Toto
\end{dingenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a useful and clever code, thank you!