# Inconsistent interline spacing in enumitem

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

I'm currently working on a set of notes and would like to encircle the item numbers in the enumerate environment. This problem largely seems to have been solved by Raphink in the thread [Enumerated list with blue circles and number inside it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50446/enumerated-list-with-blue-circles-and-number-inside-it), and their efforts are reproduced in the code below. However, as you can see, there is a slight problem around the vertical interline spacing in the paragraph corresponding to item number 2. It is inconsistent, and I would much prefer the spacing between the first and second lines to resemble the others. How would I go about this? [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=8pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item Step one 
\item Step two \lipsum[1]
\item Step three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\smash{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=8pt] (char) {#1};}}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*},itemsep=5ex]
\item Step one 
\item Step two \lipsum[1]
\item Step three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was very quick! Thank you.

Comment: @wrb98 It might be a good idea to add `topsep=...` along with `itemsep=5ex`, otherwise the text above and below the list will be very close to the first and last circles.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just as an extra point: if I later decide to ditch the circles for, say, a rounded rectangle made with \tcbox (which throws up the same spacing issues), would the \smash argument still work? If so, where should I place it?

Answer (score 4):

You want to smash the bottom of the picture, but also add empty lines depending on how many lines the item occupies.

Here I add one empty line if the item has just one line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \smash[b]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=8pt] (char) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{circledenum}{O{}+b}
 {
  \wrb_circledenum:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__wrb_circledenum_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wrb_circledenum:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__wrb_circledenum_items_seq { \item } { #2 }
  % discard the first (empty) item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__wrb_circledenum_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*},#1]
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__wrb_circledenum_items_seq
   {
    \item ##1 \par
    \int_compare:nT { \prevgraf < 3 }
     {\vspace{ \int_eval:n { 2-\prevgraf } \baselineskip }}
   }
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{circledenum}
\item Step one
\item Another short one
\item Step two \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item Step three \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item Step four \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{circledenum}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to make TeX know how many lines the previous paragraph consists of by issuing `\par` so that the number is stored in `\prevgraf`.

[image]

*Caveat*. You can't nest other lists, but I don't think it's a problem for this application.