# Add a bubble in the enumeration environment

Tags: enumerate

How can I add a bubble in the enum environment as well as shown in the image?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Adapt something like [enumerate - Enumerated list with blue circles and number inside it - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50446/enumerated-list-with-blue-circles-and-number-inside-it) but use TikZ's `ball` instead