# Exam Class : Starting question with question number in circle

Tags: exam, questionnaire

I'm studying exam class to generate question paper sample tex file is mentioned below:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}   \begin{multicols}{2} \begin{questions}
\question[4] Question 
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
 \end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

How Can I Start question with , question id in circle ; something mentioned in the image below? [image: Circle]

Comment: have you seen [Using circled numbers for answer choices in exam document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34735)

Comment: Thanks cmhughes. Using post shared by you & solution provided by kmacinnis, i'm able to put circle around question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that I originally got this from a question here, but now I can't find it.

This is what I use:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt, text=white] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse: 
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
 \end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: Question Number Circled]