# Customizing enumerations and itemizations

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

Is there a guide out there on how to customize the `enumerate` and `itemize` instances in my code?  (I'm using the Memoir class in LaTeX for Windows, and I have the `enumitem` package included.)  I want to mess with the margins and spacings to make my lists look a little less "LaTeX-default"...

Comment: Why not just look at the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)? It includes a number of examples contained with section **13 Samples** (p 13). Look at that - section and page match! `:)`

Comment: The memoir class includes code that emulates the `enumerate` package, but `enumitem` is more powerful. I would recommend not to mess much with the parameters, though, as it's easy to get wrong shape for lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is some of the default examples included in the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (section **11 Samples**). In particular, they deal with some of the spacing/margin modifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
  En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme,
  no ha mucho tiempo que viv\'{\i}a un hidalgo de los de
  \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,#1]
    \item lanza en astillero,
    \item adarna antigua,
    \item roc\'{\i}n flaco, y
    \item galgo corredor.
  \end{enumerate}
  Una olla de algo m\'{a}s vaca que carnero, salpic\'{o}n las m\'{a}s
  noches, duelos y quebrantos los s\'{a}bados\ldots
}
\begin{document}
\mylist{labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*} \par\medskip\hrule\medskip
\mylist{leftmargin=*} \par\medskip\hrule\medskip % labelindent=0pt by default
\mylist{leftmargin=\parindent} \par\medskip\hrule\medskip
\mylist{labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*, label=\Roman*., widest=IV, align=left} \par\medskip\hrule\medskip
\mylist{label=\fbox{\arabic*}}
\end{document}
```

Also see [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) for a way to use `enumitem` to encircle the enumeration using [`tikz/pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Finally, [searching for questions about `enumitem`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=enumitem) leads to many requests regarding "messing around with margins and spacing."

Comment: Is there a way to set the default for `enumerate` and `itemize` so that when I use `\begin{enumerate}`, it automatically uses the settings I want (instead of having to type `{labelindent = ..., leftmargin = ...}`, etc.?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Yes, see the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), section **5 Global settings** (p 9): `\setlist[enumerate,<level>]{<format>}` and `\setlist[itemize,<level>]{<format>}`. Note the use of `<level>`, since you can have nested lists. That is, you define the default setting for a specific `<level>` within `enumerate` or `itemize` (or `description` for that matter).

Comment: There is no Section 13 in http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf

Comment: @Viesturs: It's now section **11 Samples**. I've updated the answer.