# Escape the ] character

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerated list with square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42905/enumerated-list-with-square-brackets)

Using the help of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37887/9757), I am trying to create a list in which each item is numbered by `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=[\arabic*]]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, because the `]` character signifies the end of the `[label=`, I'm getting lots of errors.

Is there a way to "escape" the `]` character so that this does not happen?  Or is there a better way to make this list in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enclose the label within a `{}` as in `label={[\arabic*]}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Another option, not requiring additional braces, is to use `\lbrack`, `\rbrack` as in `\begin{enumerate}[label=\lbrack\arabic*\rbrack]`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks!  Peter's answer is more convenient to implement, but your solution more directly addresses the question I posed.  I'm sure that if you turn it into an answer, you'll get some upvotes! `:)`