# Itemize character

Tags: symbols, itemize

I want to change bullet in itemize to specific char but I can't find solution how to put '^' and ']' char in to this... Any thoughts?

```
\begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.5em,labelsep=1cm,leftmargin=*]
\item[+] A
\item[-] B
\item[\^] C

\item [ $]$] ] D
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52499/escape-the-character

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 4):

Add `\usepackage{enumitem}` to customize the labels. All the label syntax used below come from existing existing answers. To display a caret, preface it with `\string`. For the $, preface it with `\` and for ], preface with `\char`. For the backslash, `\textbackslash` works here.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.5em,labelsep=1cm,leftmargin=*]
        \item[+] A
        \item[-] B
        \item[\string^] C %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex-hat
        \item [\$] D
        \item [\char`\]] E
        \item [\textbackslash] F %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The ^ works but the ] and \ doesn't...

Comment: @user3490530. ] and \ are now added. Be sure to check out the other related answers, which are very informative.