# Tex codes for putting a character inside a circle

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)

Like that of copyright or registered symbols, how can I put a number/letter inside a circle?  I would like to use that in some inline formula.