# pasting small circled (\textcircled) letters leads to incorrect (reversed) Unicode codepoint sequence for combining circle

Tags: symbols, pdftex, unicode, copy-paste, accsupp

When I try to circle a small letter, compile (using `glyphtounicode.tex`), and then paste the resulting text, the combining circle (U+20DD) appears *before* the letter (here: "b") even though it, being a Unicode combining character, should always appear *after*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\input glyphtounicode
  \pdfgentounicode=1
%\usepackage{accsupp}

%\newcommand*{\textcircledcorrected}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=???? 20DD}\textcircled{#1}\EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}
a\textcircled{\tiny b}c
%a\textcircledcorrected{\tiny b}c
\end{document}
```

(This problem does not arise when the letter is of sufficient size.)

When I try to fix this using `accsupp` (see the commented-out lines above), I run into an impasse: If I use the `method=hex` and `unicode` options, I can specify the combining circle (U+20DD) as `20DD`, but I'd need to convert the letter argument (`#1`) to its Unicode codepoint, **or** I'd need some way of specifying the U+20DD character otherwise (using perhaps the `method=pdfstringdef` option) while keeping the `#1`-argument as is.

Unfortunately I cannot use UTF-8 as the input encoding on my system.

Is there a good way of defining a `\textcircledcorrected` command (using `accsupp` I suppose) that always pastes the combining circle after the enclosed character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pdfstringdef` supports `\textcircled`, thus the following works, if `#1` contains one symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input glyphtounicode
  \pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand*{\textcircledcorrected}[1]{%
  \BeginAccSupp{
    method=pdfstringdef,
    unicode,
    ActualText={\textcircled{#1}},%
  }%
    \textcircled{#1}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}

a\textcircledcorrected{\tiny b}c

\end{document}
```

BTW, without `accsupp` the PDF code contains the characters in the right order, `#1` comes first, then the circle. Because of the overlapping, the circle is put a little to the left. The amount of the left shift is larger for the letter in `\tiny`. Thus it depends on the heuristics, how to deal with that in the PDF viewer. Your PDF viewer apparently decided to switch the characters in that case.