# TikZ node causing problems inside a \caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

Following an example offered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045), I want to insert colored, circled numbers referring to items in a figure (figure details left as an exercise to the reader) into my text. The numbers are defined like this:

```
\definecolor{highlightcolor}{RGB}{241,90,36}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,fill=highlightcolor,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\textcolor{white}#1};}}
```

which I refer to in my text as `\circled{1}`, `\circled{2}`, etc. Works like a charm. The problem occurs when I try to add this command inside a figure `\caption{}`. LateX complains bitterly, accusing me of this, among other unprintable things:

```
main.tex:121 Use of \tikz@picture doesn't match its definition.
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.121 ... indicator; 7: currently-selected page. }

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried protecting the command inside the caption? `\caption{\protect\circled{1}}`.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to protect the command:

```
\caption{\protect\circled{1}}
```

Another option is to have defined `\circled` as robust in the first place