# Creating shapes like circle, rotated squares, and triangle without tikz

Tags: color, diagrams, shapes

In the previous post, I got help with creating boxes with black borders and custom fills.

How can I create other shapes like triangles, circles, rotated squares, etc. with custom fills.

I do not want to use tikz at this moment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

% some color definitions
\definecolor{cblue}{RGB}{16,78,139}
\definecolor{cred}{RGB}{139,37,0}
\definecolor{cgreen}{RGB}{0,139,0} 

% normal box
\newcommand{\sqboxs}{1.2ex}% the square size
\newcommand{\sqboxf}{0.6pt}% the border in \sqboxEmpty
\newcommand{\sqbox}[1]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\sqboxs}{\sqboxs}}}
\newcommand{\sqboxblack}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\sqbox{#1}}}

% empty box
\newcommand{\sqboxEmpty}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{\sqboxf}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \textcolor{#1}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\sqboxs}\rule{\sqboxs}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\sqboxEmptyblack}[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\sqboxEmpty{#1}}}

\begin{document}
I like these.
\sqbox{cred}  \sqbox{cgreen} \sqbox{cblue}

And also these.
\sqboxEmpty{cred}  \sqboxEmpty{cgreen}  \sqboxEmpty{cblue}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `pstricks`  or `pst-poly` for regular polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I approve of your decision not to use TikZ. You can create various shapes by low level PDF commands, as is used in my code here. We define `\sqbox` for square, `\trianbox` for triangle, `\uptrianbox` for rotated triangle, `\circbox` for circle and `\diabox` for diamonds. All these macros have two parameters: first one is `0` if we need outlined shape or `1` if we need solid shape. Second one is the color defined by `\def\nameCOLOR`.

```
\def\sqPDF#1#2{0 0 m #1 0 l #1 #1 l 0 #1 l h}
\def\trianPDF#1#2{0 0 m #1 0 l #2 4.5 l h}
\def\uptrianPDF#1#2{#2 0 m #1 4.5 l 0 4.5 l h}
\def\circPDF#1#2{#1 0 0 #1 #2 #2 cm .1 w .5 0 m
   .5 .276 .276 .5 0 .5 c -.276 .5 -.5 .276 -.5 0 c
   -.5 -.276 -.276 -.5 0 -.5 c .276 -.5 .5 -.276 .5 0 c h}
\def\diaPDF#1#2{#2 0 m #1 #2 l #2 #1 l 0 #2 l h}

\def\credCOLOR   {.54 .14 0}
\def\cblueCOLOR  {.06 .3 .54}
\def\cgreenCOLOR {0 .54 0}

\def\genbox#1#2#3#4#5#6{% #1=0/1, #2=color, #3=shape, #4=raise, #5=width, #6=width/2
    \leavevmode\raise#4bp\hbox to#5bp{\vrule height#5bp depth0bp width0bp
    \pdfliteral{q .5 w \csname #2COLOR\endcsname\space RG
                       \csname #3PDF\endcsname{#5}{#6} S Q
             \ifx1#1 q \csname #2COLOR\endcsname\space rg 
                       \csname #3PDF\endcsname{#5}{#6} f Q\fi}\hss}}

                                    % shape     raise width  width/2
\def\sqbox      #1#2{\genbox{#1}{#2}  {sq}       {0}   {4.5}  {2.25}}
\def\trianbox   #1#2{\genbox{#1}{#2}  {trian}    {0}   {5}    {2.5}}
\def\uptrianbox #1#2{\genbox{#1}{#2}  {uptrian}  {0}   {5}    {2.5}}
\def\circbox    #1#2{\genbox{#1}{#2}  {circ}     {0}   {5}    {2.5}}
\def\diabox     #1#2{\genbox{#1}{#2}  {dia}      {-.5} {6}    {3}}

%% usage:

squares: \sqbox0{cgreen}, \sqbox1{cred}, \sqbox0{cblue}.

triangles: \trianbox0{cgreen}, \trianbox1{cred}, \trianbox0{cblue}.

triangles: \uptrianbox0{cgreen}, \uptrianbox1{cred}, \uptrianbox0{cblue}.

circles: \circbox0{cgreen}, \circbox1{cred}, \circbox0{cblue}.

diamonds: \diabox0{cgreen}, \diabox1{cred}, \diabox0{cblue}.
```

The result:

[image: shapes]

You need not any package for this. Nor `xcolor`. All stuff is done at PDF low level commands. If you are using XeTeX (no pdfTeX) then you need to define `\pdfliteral` by:

```
\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}
```

I tried this in plain TeX but I hope that the code will work in LaTeX too (after adding `\documentclass` etc. sequences).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it preferred not to use Tikz?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,xcolor}
\begin{document}
    How about this?
    \rlap{\color{green}$\filledlargestar$}\color{red}$\largepentagram$
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. The document that I am writing is a PhD thesis - so, this kind of symbol will not be accepted. but, I will check out the MnSymbol package.

Comment: @abhishek It does not require symbols from specific package. Any outlined-filled-pair of symbol is OK. For instance, `amsmath` contains many triangles.

Comment: I am struggling badly with this. can you help me. I recently posted another question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220132/defining-a-tikz-shape-with-different-fills-in-a-figure-caption       can you check and help me with this?