# defining a tikz shape with different fills in a figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Below is the output I want]

In the graph captions of my thesis, I want to define 3 triangles with 3 fills (yellow, red, and black). For one triangle, it works fine. How can I define the two other triangles with different fills.

Below is the MWE of thesis and the chapter:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside,10pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{255,255,0}      % yellow
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{255,0,0}        % red
\definecolor{mycolor3}{RGB}{0,0,0}          % black

\newrobustcmd*{\mytriangle}[1]{\tikz{\draw[thick, fill=mycolor1] ((0,0) -- (0.2cm,0) -- (0.1cm,0.2cm) -- cycle;}}

%\newrobustcmd*{\mytriangle}[1]{\tikz{\draw[thick, fill=mycolor2] ((0,0) -- (0.2cm,0) -- (0.1cm,0.2cm) -- cycle;}}
%\newrobustcmd*{\mytriangle}[1]{\tikz{\draw[thick, fill=mycolor2] ((0,0) -- (0.2cm,0) -- (0.1cm,0.2cm) -- cycle;}}

\begin{document}

this is my thesis 


\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

This is the code for the chapter Introduction:

```
\chapter{introduction}


\begin{figure}[htp]


  A figure
 \caption{This is a triangle {\mytriangle{mycolor1}}}


\end{figure}
```

Comment: Define just one command accepting as (mandatory) argument the fill color: `\newrobustcmd*{\mytriangle}[1]{\tikz{\draw[thick, fill=#1]  (0,0) -- (0.2cm,0) -- (0.1cm,0.2cm) -- cycle;}}`. Invoke it as `\mytriangle{<color>}`. Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: @PierPaolo  Your code gives me one triangle with one fill; how do I define the same triangle now with 2 more different fills?  If I define color with different fills in your argument, I get the error that \mytriangle is already defined. I want the caption as {this is a triangle \mytriangle{mycolor1} and another triangle \mytriangle{mycolor2})

Comment: Could you post a picture (even drawn by hand) of what you want?

Comment: @PierPaolo   see the picture; apologies if I did not explain it clearly

Comment: @abhishek Do you want triangles, squares, circles or all three at once?

Comment: @PaulGaborit   I want all of them actually.

Comment: @abhishek, Pier Paolo's comment should do exactly what you want... Just type exactly what you said before (`this is a triangle \mytriangle{mycolor1} and another triangle \mytriangle{mycolor2}`) with the definition as provided and it should work.

Comment: @PaulGessler  I have already tried that. for me, it is not working. If I do that, I get the error Command \mytriangle already feined. or name \end... illegal, see p. 192 of the manual. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX companion for explanation. Can you give it a try and see if it works at your end?

Comment: You have to define the command only once. Then you use whenever you wish.

Comment: @Sigur  Are you suggesting that I should make new commands for triangles with different fills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @Pier Paolo comment, you can make use of the command `\mytriangle` with an argument. The argument is used to pass the colour you want.

**1.** Note that you don't need to define those colours. They are already defined when you load `tikz`. So you just use `\mytriangle{red}`.

**2.** Note that your original triangle (produced with `(0,0) -- (0.2cm,0) -- (0.1cm,0.2cm) -- cycle`) is not an equilateral triangle.

So I decided to make use of polar coordinates to create an equilateral one inscribed on a circle with radius `\radius`. Note the use of

```
\newlength{\radius} \setlength{\radius}{.2cm}
```

**3.** I also defined other two commands which work in the same way, with mandatory argument for colours.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{255,255,0}      % yellow
%%\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{255,0,0}        % red
%%\definecolor{mycolor3}{RGB}{0,0,0}          % black
\newlength{\radius}
\setlength{\radius}{.2cm}

\newrobustcmd*{\mytriangle}[1]{\tikz{\draw[thick, fill=#1] (90:\radius) -- (210:\radius) -- (330:\radius) -- cycle;}}

\newrobustcmd*{\mysquare}[1]{\tikz{\draw[thick, fill=#1] (45:\radius) -- (135:\radius) -- (225:\radius) -- (315:\radius) -- cycle;}}

\newrobustcmd*{\mycircle}[1]{\tikz{\draw[thick, fill=#1] (0,0)  circle (\radius);}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1] \mytriangle{yellow} \quad \mytriangle{red} \quad \mytriangle{black}
%
\lipsum*[2] \mysquare{yellow} \quad \mysquare{red} \quad \mysquare{black}
%
\lipsum*[5] \mycircle{yellow} \quad \mycircle{red} \quad \mycircle{black}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this way, it also works in my document. But, when I put it in a "Chapter" of a thesis, it does not work. Can you try that? I am trying it too.

Comment: @abhishek, be careful. I loaded the package `lipsum` only to produce random text. In fact, you will need to load only `tikz` and `etoolbox`. What is the error?

Comment: Yes, I am aware. Ok, it seems to work now. I will place this in my thesis and see how it works out. I am very curious.

Comment: Yes, FINALLY, it all works fine now. I am glad! thanks all for the help!

Comment: @abhishek, just to let you know: if you want a grey color you can pass the percentage of black. Use `black!60` for example, to 60% black.

Comment: For that, I modified your command fill=#1] to fill=mycolor] and then, I define mycolor with RGB. So, I have then the freedom for the whole spectrum.

Comment: @abhishek, this is not a good idea because you are defining a command with constant colour `mycolor`. So I agree that you can define a lot of new colours but you should use them as arguments for the command ('fill=#1`).

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. I used your command with fill=#1 and defined different colors with mycolor , like what you said. Sorry about the confusion.