# How do I encircle text? Like make a circle around it?

Tags: math-mode, mathjax

I would like to know how make a circle and then insert text. There has to be a way.. right?

Comment: The easier mode is to use `node` within `tikz`. But you have to explain better what you want, where you wish to use it, etc...

Comment: @Sigur What is that? Im new to this so I just wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: OK, it is possible. See here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/nodes-and-shapes/

Comment: @Sigur note the OP has tagged this mathjax

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about MathJax.

Comment: I don't think questions should be closed OT simply because they use the [tag:mathjax] tag. Otherwise why have it? It is phrased in general, and does have latex answers, some of which might apply to mathjax as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm almost sure (or not) that OP tagged randomly.

Comment: @Sigur if we ignore the tags then the question should _definitely_ not be closed OT:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know what that tag is doing here. MathJax questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if it's about LaTeX then it's a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Pure mathjax questions are OT, as are pure emacs questions or pure environment variable setup questions, but questions involving overlap are possible and I think reasonable to answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina arguably yes, although that is about numbers specifically (single character rather than arbitrary text) at least the question is, the answer is more general.

Comment: FWIW The closest I've found in mathjax is \boxed{a}, I couldn't find a way to circle text in mathjax unfortunately (as of now \tikz doesn't work in mathjax)

Comment: Related (and very rich): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latex has a `\textcircled` command for making a fixed size circle around a letter `\textcircled{R}` and its picture mode has a `\circle` command for making circles in a range of sizes (or arbitrary size if you use `pict2e`).

You don't mention mathjax but I note you tagged the question mathjax. Mathjax specific questions are off topic, but I'll note that mathjax does not support either of the above commands but you can do

```
\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\color{black}{x}}
```

If you use its enclose extension.

Comment: I think it looks better with downscaling the character, e.g. \textcircled{\scalebox{0.7}{3}} (tested in LaTeX only)

Comment: @cknoll It does seem to need some alignment, but I don't think your command is correct. Can you give an example trying to encircle the letter 'M'?

Comment: Indeed. It seems to depend on the font. If I use `\usepackage{lmodern}` (for my preferred font) then `\textcircled{\raisebox{0.14em}{\scalebox{0.5}{M}}}` gives good results. It uses `\raisebox` to shift the glyph upwards. Note that `\raisebox` also accepts negative values for its first argument.

Comment: When I do `\textcircled{R}` circle is kind of small, it is possible to make it larger ?

Comment: `{\large\textcircled{R}}`? @alper