# \enclose undefined control sequence

Tags: equations, mathjax

We noted the following TeX code support in mathjax in referring in the net but it is undefined while compiling in latex, what package I should used here?

```
$$\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\color{black}{x}}$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new `circledsteps` package. Please use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`, see [the answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\newcommand{\CCircled}[2][]{\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/csteps/.cd,inner color=.,#1}%
\ifmmode
\Circled{$#2$}%
\else
\Circled{#2}%
\fi
\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\[\CCircled[outer color=red]{x}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What standard package to support \enclose tex code?

Comment: @RajeshN I am not aware of any. See this related answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229010.

Comment: Thank you Schrödinger's, I copied tex code from above mentioned site, but what package to support \enclose command info not given.

Comment: @RajeshN Why do you think that every MathJax command is realized as a LaTeX command of the same name? As I said, I do not think there is a standard package that defines `\enclose` in *LaTeX*, but of course I may be wrong. (The downvote is not from me, I do not downvote.)

Comment: In my understanding MathJax support latex coding that defined in the style file or standard tex coding.

Comment: @RajeshN I have only very limited experience with MathJax, but according to what I know this is not the case. MathJax mimics LaTeX in many regards, but not all. Well, let's see if someone else finds the `\enclose` command in some standard package. (To be clear, there is no problem in defining a command that does what `\enclose` does. I am just doubting that there is a standard package that carries this command.)

Comment: @RajeshN Remember, this is important: **MathJax has absolutely nothing to do with LaTeX.** They are two different projects, unrelated to each other. MathJax may use TeX math commands but they can also invent their own. Your understanding is wrong.

Comment: @RajeshN adding to the above comments, `mathjax`, in general, is out-of-scope of this site.

Comment: Thank you Fractal for your explanation.