# circle around a number

Tags: tables, circles

I just have a little question. I do not know how exactly it works, but may I also make such a circle like on the photo below? The one which I have is not rounded like this and the line is very tight at the numbers. Hope you understand what I mean. Thank you for your help!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} 
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{multirow,array}
    \usepackage{arydshln}  
    \usepackage{tikz}        
    \dashlinegap=1pt                   
    \usepackage{acronym}

    \newcommand\mybox[3][]{%
        \tikz[anchor=base,baseline]\node[inner sep=2pt,draw=#2,#1]{$\displaystyle#3\mathstrut$};}
    \colorlet{mycol}{black}


    \begin{document}

        \begin{table}
            \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
            \begin{tabular}{*{5}{>{$}c<{$}}}
                & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player II}& \\ 
                & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{H}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{T} & \underset{s_1 \in S_1}{min} \, u(s_1, s_2) \\\cline{3-4}
                \multirow{2}*{Player I}
                & H & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-1} &\multicolumn{1}{l}{-1} \\ \cline{3-4}
                & T & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{-1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-1} &\multicolumn{1}{l}{-1} \\ \cline{3-4}
                \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{$\underset{s_2 \in S_2}{min} \, u(s_1, s_2)$} & & 1 &1 & 
                \multicolumn{1}{l}{\mybox[rounded corners]{mycol}{1,1}}

            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [**Good way to make \textcircled numbers?**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want but here are a few options. Using `inner sep` you can enlarge the distance between the text and borders. If you only want to increase the horizontal distance use `inner xsep=`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}        

\newcommand\mybox[3][]{%
    \tikz[anchor=base,baseline]\node[inner sep=2pt,draw=#2,#1]{$\displaystyle#3\mathstrut$};}
\colorlet{mycol}{black}


\begin{document}
    \mybox[rounded corners]{mycol}{1,1}
    \mybox[rounded corners=2pt]{mycol}{1,1}
    \mybox[rounded corners=6pt]{mycol}{1,1}
    \mybox[rounded corners=6pt, inner sep=2pt]{mycol}{1,1}
    \mybox[rounded corners=6pt, inner sep=4pt]{mycol}{1,1}
    \mybox[rounded corners=6pt, inner sep=6pt]{mycol}{1,1}

    \mybox[rounded corners=6pt, line width=1pt, draw=red, fill=yellow!25]{mycol}{1,1}
    
    \mybox[rounded corners=6pt, line width=1pt, draw=blue, fill=green!25, inner xsep=8pt]{mycol}{1,1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I do not know how to explain it in English. But is it also possible to widen the circle like on the photo above? But it would be superb if the height would remain the same...Thank you for your help : )

Comment: @hpz1719: Have updated the solution to show how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to use the two options available in Ti*k*Z that are `minimum width` and `minimum height`. If you do not change the `inner sep` that would give the result you want:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node[rounded corners,draw] {0,1}; \tikz \node[rounded corners,draw,minimum width=1cm] {0,1}; \tikz \node[rounded corners,draw,minimum width=2cm] {0,1};\\

\tikz \node[rounded corners,draw,minimum height=1cm] {0,1}; \tikz \node[rounded corners,draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm] {0,1};
\end{document}
```

[image: Options minimum width and minimum height]

You can then define a new command, in this case the optional argument is the minimum width:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2][0]{\tikz \node[draw,rounded corners,minimum width=#1] {#2};}
\begin{document}
\mybox{1,1} \mybox[1cm]{1,1} \mybox[1.5cm]{1,1}
\end{document}
```

[image: \mybox]

If you do not specify the optional argument the dimension of the box is set according to `inner sep`.

Comment: Thank you also for your help!! I am sorry I cannot klick twice on the checkmark sign...

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,array, siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand\myovalbox[1]{ \psframebox[framearc=1, framesep=4pt, linecolor=IndianRed3]{\hskip 0.33em#1\hskip 0.33em}}

\begin{document}

\[ \myovalbox{\num{1,3}} \quad\myovalbox{\num{1,333}}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]