# TikZ - Circled text number in superscript - Missing $

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, formatting, superscripts

I'm using TikZ to create some circles with numbers as some sort of marker. But I want to use them as superscript.

So to **generate a circle** I'm using this command (suggested here: [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)):

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {#1};}}
```

To use it within the text (as **superscript**) I'm using:

```
text^{\circled{1}}
```

However I get the following **error**:

```
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Missing $ inserted. ... & 24 &
> 8 & 32^{\circleds{3}} & (followed by: 0      & 24    & 8
> \\)   doc.tex /doc line 287   Texlipse Build Error
```

Any suggestions of why is that?

Here is an small code example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document} 
This works: \circled{3}. But this^{\circled{1}} is no good.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: The superscript character `^` is a command to be used in math mode.  If you provided a minimal version of the code that fails, we could answer more definitively, but `text^{anything}` will fail irrespective of `tikz`, if it is not already in math mode.  Maybe try `text\textsuperscript{\circled{1}}`

Comment: ^ works only in math mode, so you may try `$text^{\circled{1}}$`

Comment: Just tried. It seems to ignore the \circled{1} and just place the number 1.

Comment: @SAM That would but the "text" part in math mode too,

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i didnt understnad well, the circle should include 'text' too ?

Comment: No. The circle should include only the number.

Comment: @SAM What I meant was that `text` & `$text$` will produce different output (the former roman, the latter italic and spaced oddly).  Your suggestion would make the "text" italic, whereas the context of the question makes it seem as if "text" should be roman.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes what about `$\text{text}^{\circled{1}}$`

Comment: @SAM Yes on that suggestion, or even `text$^{\circled{1}}$`

Comment: @SAM this doesn't work but it gives a different error message. ***Undefined control sequence***

Comment: @rkioji no it works you only have to load `amsmath` `\text` is defined in that package.

Comment: Indeed, I've missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in numerous comments, the underlying problem was that `^` was invoked in text, not math mode.  Here are two possibilities, depending on how you want it to behave.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document} 
This works: \circled{3}. But this\textsuperscript{\circled{1}} is no good.

This works: \circled{3}. But this$^{\circled{1}}$ is no good.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!! You guys are ninja!! That works.