# Circle Font Awesome Icons

Tags: circles, fontawesome

I need to circle font awesome icons.
Currently, this is how it looks.
[image]

The code for this is:

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faDesktop shubhamrathi.in
\faEnvelope hello@shubhamrathi.in
\faPhone +91-9985556304
\faGithub srrathi
\faLinkedin /in/shubhamrrathi

\end{document}
```

I need icons to be enclosed in a circle like this:

[image]

How should this be done? I'm preferably looking for a solution without pstricks ( one which works with Sharelatex)

Comment: Must  the circles all  have the same size, or be adjusted to the glyph size?

Comment: Same Size for all circles.

Comment: ICan you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Updated the question with MWE. Thanks for curating the question.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution based on `pstricks`. I define a `\pscircled{#1}` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\pscircled[1]{%
\raisebox{-0.315\height}{\begin{postscript}
\Cnodeput[radius=2.3ex](0,0){P}{#1}
\end{postscript}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent       
\pscircled{\faDesktop}~\href{www.shubhamrathi.in}{shubhamrathi.in}
\enspace 
\pscircled{\faEnvelope}~hello@shubhamrathi.in
\enspace 
\pscircled{\faPhone}~+91-9985556304\\
%
\pscircled{\faGithub}~srrathi
\enspace 
\pscircled{\faLinkedin}~/in/shubhamrrathi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've followed your steps but the icons have disappeared. Please see this sharelatex file: https://goo.gl/SrsVa4

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention, for pstricks commands to work with pdflatex, you have to launch it with the `-shell-escape` switch.

Comment: How do you launch with `-shell-escape`in Sharelatex?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use Share LaTeX  and have no idea. If this is not possible  (for security reasons), I suggest you write individual graphic files for each of the circled icons in the classic way (latex -> dvips ->pstopdf) as  `standalone` files, and use them with `\includegraphics`. For this method, `\raisebox{-0.315\height}` command can be removed.

Comment: I see. Writing individual files was always an option but I would prefer a solution that is compatible with Sharelatex too.
Nonetheless, this is help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution with `\textcircled` and `\resizebox`:

> [image: simple MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fontawesome}
\def\ci#1{\textcircled{\resizebox{.5em}{!}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\ci{\faDesktop} shubhamrathi.in\par
\ci{\faEnvelope} hello@shubhamrathi.in\par
\ci{\faPhone} +91-9985556304\par
\ci{\faGithub} srrathi\par
\ci{\faLinkedin} /in/shubhamrrathi\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: This caused the icons to shrink a bit. I've found a solution, have posted it below.

Comment: @user3426358 The was the idea, so that  the circle size is consistent with the size of circles surrounding a normal character. If you  want bigger circled icons you can always use a bigger font for the circle and resize the icon accordingly (some like  `{\Large\textcircled{\resizebox{.6em}{!}{\faDesktop}}}` )  but a larger icon does not look very nice, IMHO, at least with single spacing.

Answer (score 2):

With `scalerel` and `stackengine` (what else?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\srcircled[1]{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2ex}{\scalerel*{$#1$}{x}}{\textcircled{\strut}}}
\begin{document}
\srcircled{\faDesktop}~\href{www.shubhamrathi.in}{shubhamrathi.in}\par
\srcircled{\faEnvelope}~hello@shubhamrathi.in\par
\srcircled{\faPhone}~+91-9985556304\par
\srcircled{\faGithub}~srrathi\par
\srcircled{\faLinkedin}~/in/shubhamrrathi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After reading around more on the forum, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) has helped me get the right solution.

```
\usepackage{hyperref, tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\circled{\faDesktop}~{shubhamrathi.in}
\circled{\faEnvelope}~hello@shubhamrathi.in
\circled{\faPhone}~9985556304
\circled{\faGithub}~ShubhamRathi
\circled{\faLinkedin}/in/ShubhamRRathi
```

This looks such:
[image]