# Using fontawesome icons

Tags: symbols, fontawesome

Writing my CV, I try to put symbols of email, phone, twitter, etc before the corresponding information on top of my CV. So, I basically did the following:

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res} % Use the res.cls style, the font size can be changed to 11pt or 12pt here
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{helvet} % Default font is the helvetica postscript font
%\usepackage{newcent} % To change the default font to the new century schoolbook postscript font uncomment this line and comment the one above
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % Text width of the document
\begin{document}

\mobile{+1...}
\twitter{...}

\end{document}
```

However, I receive the "Undefined control sequence" error. I tried to follow one of the templates but couldn't understand what causes the problem here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: Possible related as an help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332196/circle-font-awesome-icons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `res` class from https://ctan.org/pkg/res. This was last updated in 2001, so I doubt it has special commands in place to insert your twitter contact. However you can simply input the icons like this:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faMobile\ +1... 

\faTwitter\ ... 


\end{document}
```

[image]