# Numbers inside triangles

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I found a good answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) about how to insert characters into circles, but how could one place a triangular order around a character? Would it involve $\triangle$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified Stefan Kottwitz answer on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes}
\newcommand*\triangled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \triangled{1} \triangled{2} \triangled{3} etc.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So @zarko I'm trying to use this on the Mathematics site and it's not working; all that happens is a black box appears around the text…

Comment: @user56478, in your question is not given any context how you will use this "triangled" numbers/characters. I'm sorry, I don't know Mathematics site nor how is there published images.

Comment: Ah, okay…  I'll search for an answer online.  It can't be too complicated to convert over from normal LaTeX.