# A white number inside a black circle.

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

How to make a white number inside a black circle (the picture below)? I want to change numbers inside the black circle, of course.  I use *Share LaTeX*. I have read some articles here but anyone are not what I would like to get. I would like to get this [an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) (the picture below) - the sixth answer.

Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: Stating the number of an answer is completely useless, there are at least 3 different orders they can be displayed in - sorted by age, activity or number of votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Created from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045/135930)  linked in the question above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\textcolor{white}{#1}};}}

\begin{document}
\circled{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @P. Siehr: Wouldn't it be a better way to just post a comment on the link to the (already) existing answer instead of just copying it?

Comment: @CampanIgnis That might have been better, yes. The problem is, I lack the reputation to create comments ...

Answer (score 6):

In what context do you want to use the numbers?

This does work in many situations. Observe that the color of the number and the circle are chosen automatically.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\ballnumber}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(myanchor.base)] \node[circle,fill=.,inner sep=1pt] (myanchor) {\color{-.}\bfseries\footnotesize #1};}

\begin{document}
Earum excepturi inventore necessitatibus aliquid reiciendis enim.  \ballnumber{37} Earum excepturi inventore necessitatibus aliquid reiciendis enim.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit:The question [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/128553) is related.

The package https://ctan.org/pkg/circledtext is an alternative.

Comment: I want to use it as a symbol next to a text in the line.

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič You mean as a symbol inline or like on the margin?

Comment: Can you change size a bit, please. It is still too much large. Thanks.

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič You can change the size yourself with `font=\tiny` or `font=\footnotesize` in the node options.

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič: You are very welcome.