# How to style when writing code with minted or listings

Tags: listings, minted

I have some style references to use style in python highlighted code:
[image]

**or**

[image]

---

**Can you achieve this type of style with minted or listings? By the way, the language is Python.**

please give an example of how it is used

Comment: This should be possible using both packages and some options like `escapeinside`. (The first one seems to be more `minted`-like, the second one more `lstlisting`-like.) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just for clarity, you are asking about how to add these circled numbers to your listings?

Comment: @siracusa Yes, My question is as achievement this design with the package `minted`? but I would like you to **make an example**

Comment: You received an answer, but we generally like to see some sort of effort on the part of those asking questions (much more than just posting two pictures).  It would have been preferable to also include the TeX code you used to create the output you showed us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A solution sketch using the `listings` package**

As suggested in the comments, with the `listings` package you can use the `escapeinside` option to escape from the verbatim typesetting context to call a macro that outputs a circled number.

The `\circled` macro is inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374932/a-white-number-inside-a-black-circle/374945#374945) but with some additions to make the circles have a fixed size. Also the background and text color can be passed as a parameter.

For the circled notes after certain lines in the listing, `escapeinside = {<@}{@>}` was set to escape the listing. Within those delimiters we then can use the `\lstnote{...}` macro to add a fixed amount of spacing plus the number in a circle.

For the circled line numbers another macro `\circledstyle` was defined. We make `listings` typeset line numbers using this style by adding the `numberstyle = \circledstyle` option.

The full example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\circled[3]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt, text width=8pt, align=center]
            (char) {\textcolor{#2}{\sffamily\bfseries\scriptsize #3}};
    }%
}

\newcommand\lstnote[1]{%
    \kern 1.5em%
    \circled{purple}{pink!50!white}{#1}%
}

\newcommand\circledstyle[1]{%
    \circled{gray}{white}{#1}%
}

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    language = [LaTeX]TeX,
    texcsstyle = *\color{blue},
    escapeinside = {<@}{@>},
    backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray!30!white},
    framexleftmargin = 3em,
    framerule = 0pt,
    frame = tb,
    numbers = left,
    numberstyle = \circledstyle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article} <@ \lstnote{1} @>
\usepackage{xcolor}  <@ \lstnote{2} @>

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{Hello world!} <@ \lstnote{3} @>

New paragraph.

And another one.
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect your code and explanations! :-)

Comment: Oh great, can you configure it from an external file of the "code.tex" code?

Comment: @royer Sure, you can put the definitons into another file and `\input` it or even [create a new package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/how-do-i-create-a-latex-package) for them