# How to customize math symbols?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to typeset a symbol in the following picture,

[image]

It's the one that is a V in a circle, as superscript of X. I want it to be a real symbol, such that it will look natural when I put it in subscript and superscript.

I searched in unicode table and this one does not seem to belong to unicode, so I assume the author made it himself. I've looked at other ways like this one [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) , but when I put the symbol in subscript, it doesn't look sized well.

How should I make up a symbol like this?

Comment: The symbol you want is `\ovee` provided with `\usepackage{stmaryrd}`. You find it listed in table 52 of the Comprehensive List, “`stmaryrd` Binary Operators”.

Comment: @egreg i didn't mention but i did try detexify. it's not there, unless my drawing is horrible. i will try that package.