# how to embed small tikz \textcircled numbers within a line in a centered way

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I would like to embed some small tikz textcircled numbers within equation lines. In the following example things starts to not be centered when the natural number exceeds 9. How should I modify my \numcircledtikzscriptsize macro which I took from the question [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers?rq=1)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\numcircledtikzscriptsize[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {\scriptsize \bf #1};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}[t]{cl}
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{1}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{2}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{3}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{3}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{4}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{5}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{6}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{7}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{8}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{9}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{10}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{11}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\tikz \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] {\numcircledtikzscriptsize{12}};&$y\leq x+1$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the nodes settings **twice** (E.g. `inner sep=-1.8pt`), which just makes things very messy. You should use your `\numcircledtikzscriptsize` as is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\numcircledtikzscriptsize[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {\scriptsize \bfseries #1};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{cl}
        \numcircledtikzscriptsize{1}  & $y\leq x+1$ \\
        \numcircledtikzscriptsize{12} & $y\leq x+1$ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

### [image: Centered]

Also you could use `\phantom` to set the "max" size, and make them all the same height like so:

```
\newcommand*\numcircledtikzscriptsize[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {\scriptsize\phantom{77}};\node at (char){\bfseries\scriptsize #1};}}
```

[image]