# Text in underbrace is too long and alignment of equation is changing

Tags: equations, alignment, underbrace

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{mat:mom}
\rho g\textsubscript{x} &- \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \mu(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}) &=\quad \rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \\
\underbrace{\rho g\textsubscript{z}}_{Body forces per unit volume} &- \underbrace{\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}}_{Pressure forces per unit volume} + \underbrace{\mu(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial z^2})}_{Viscous forces per unit volume} &= \underbrace{\quad \rho\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}}_{Inertial forces per unit volume}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

The text in underbrace is tto long and it causes the equations to be misaligned.How to split the text in underbraces to two lines. i tried using `\\`but it dooesnt seem to help.

Comment: `\textsubscript{x}` should be `_{x}`. Never use `\textsubscript` in math mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first avoid repeating “forces per unit volume”. Diagrams like these require a bit of manual work in order to get proper alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\textunderbrace}[2]{{%
  \underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{mat:mom}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcolumntype{e}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcolumntype{o}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\newcommand{\vs}{\vphantom{\biggl(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}}}
\textunderbrace{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
  \begin{array}{ e o e o e o e }
  \rho g_{x}
    &-& \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}
    &+& \mu\biggl(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
     +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
     +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\biggr)
    &=& \rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \\
  \textunderbrace{\rho g_{z}\vs}{Body}
    &-& \textunderbrace{\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}\vs}{\makebox[0pt]{Pressure}}
    &+& \textunderbrace{\mu\biggl(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}
     +  \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}
     +  \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial z^2}\biggr)}{Viscous}
    &=& \textunderbrace{\rho\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}\vs}{\makebox[0pt]{Inertial}}
  \end{array}
}{forces per unit volume}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\text` for the text below the under braces, this combined with some `\raisebox` and `\mathllap` and `\mathrlap` (provided by `mathtools`) you can get something like the following. This however doesn't look good...

Another way would be to mark the code with some counter and reference those marks to explain the code. I used some `\raisebox`es there, for better vertical alignment (the encircled letters where too close to the tips of the braces).

Also you should not use `\textsubscript` in math mode, for single letter indices (even for multiple single letters), instead use `_{<indices>}` and for a full word or an abbreviation use `_{\text{<index>}}`.

And you could consider using `\left`, `\right` braces (or manual sizing with stuff like `\big(`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% Using \mylabel to hide the \label from amsmath
\let\mylabel\label
\newcounter{eqannotate}[equation]
\renewcommand*\theeqannotate{\textcircled{\footnotesize\alph{eqannotate}}}
\newcommand*\eqannotate[1][]
  {%
    \hbox
      {%
        \begingroup
        \refstepcounter{eqannotate}%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \else
          \mylabel{#1}%
        \fi
        \endgroup
        \theeqannotate
      }%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{mat:mom}
\rho g_{x} 
  &- \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}
  + \mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2
  u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\right)
  &= \rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \\
\underbrace{\rho g_{z}}_{\mathllap{\text{Body forces per unit volume}}}
  &- \underbrace{\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}}
  _{\mathclap{\text{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{Pressure forces per unit volume}}}}
  + \underbrace{\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2
  w}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial z^2}\right)}
  _{\hspace{-2em}\mathrlap{\text{\raisebox{-2ex}{Viscous forces per unit
  volume}}}}
  &= \underbrace{\rho\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}}
  _{\mathrlap{\text{Inertial forces per unit volume}}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{mat:mom2}
\rho g_{x}
  &- \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}
  + \mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2
  u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\right)
  &= \rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \\
\underbrace{\rho g_{z}}_{\raisebox{-.5ex}{\eqannotate[an:first]}}
  &- \underbrace{\frac{\partial p}{\partial
  z}}_{\raisebox{-.5ex}{\eqannotate[an:sec]}}
  + \underbrace{\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} +
  \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial
  z^2}\right)}_{\raisebox{-.5ex}{\eqannotate[an:third]}}
  &= \underbrace{\rho\frac{\partial w}{\partial
  t}}_{\raisebox{-.5ex}{\eqannotate[an:fourth]}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
With
\ref{an:first} being the body forces per unit volume,
\ref{an:sec} the pressure forces per unit volume,
\ref{an:third} the viscous forces per unit volume,
and \ref{an:fourth} the inertial forces per unit volume.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second option looks good! But why do you need to hide \label?

Comment: @SirReal just try to use `\label` instead of `\mylabel` in `\eqannotate` and you'll see. `amsmath` environments seem to parse the used `\label`s.

Comment: You might take a look e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/117050) for better looking alternatives to `\textcircled`, if you want to, or change the definition of `\theeqannotate` completely to match your tastes.

Answer (score 1):

A variant with `stackengine`. I loaded `esdiff` for a simpler typing of partial derivatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\newcommand{\textub}[1]{\scriptsize\Shortunderstack{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
\label{mat:mom}
\rho g\textsubscript{x} &- \diffp{p}{x} & & + \mu\biggl(\diffp[2]{u}{x} + \diffp[2]{u}{y} + \diffp[2]{u}{z}\biggr) & & =\rho\diffp{u}{t} \\
\underbrace{\rho g\textsubscript{z}}_{\textub{Body\\ forces}} &- \underbrace{\diffp{p}{z}}_{\clap{\textub{Pressure\\ forces}}} & & + \underbrace{\mu\biggl(\diffp[2]{w}{x} + \diffp[2]{w}{y} + \diffp[2]{w}{z}\biggr)}_{\textub{Viscous forces}} & &= \underbrace{\rho\diffp{w}{t}}_{\clap{\textub{Inertial forces}}}\\
& & & \rlap{\scriptsize per unit volume}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]