# subscript smaller than underbrace breaks alignment

Tags: spacing, subscripts, underbrace

I have this

[image]

I have two problems: First, as you might see, when the subscript is smaller than the text in the underbrace the alignment is broken (but if the subscript is longer the alignment works perfectly). The second problem is I'm trying that the text `'parameter set'` is blue and NOT bold. Is this possible? (you can avoid using the command as I just use it because I use bold and blue a lot)

For an underbrace in a subscript, I'm using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5442/underbrace-and-subscripts) solution. And when I try the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437735/text-in-underbrace-is-too-long-and-alignment-of-equation-is-changing) for subscript smaller than underbrace I got this: (I replace `\underbrace` by `\textunderbrace` in the code below for this output, as stated in the solution linked)

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\boldblue[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\boldblue{$(E,\{P_\theta\}_{\underbrace{\scriptstyle{\theta \in \Theta}}_\text{parameter set}})$}

\end{document}
```

PS: I would like to keep it simple, so I would prefer to avoid using more packages than `AMS` and `xcolor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}
\newcommand\boldblue[1]{{\color{blue}\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}
\boldblue{($E$,$\{P_\theta\}^{}_{%
    \underbrace{\scriptstyle\theta\in\Theta}%
    _{\mathclap{\textnormal{parameter set}}}}$)}
\end{document}
```