# circling a parameter in a formula

Tags: equations

How can I insert a circle around a parameter in a formula or in a text as below one:
[image]

Comment: Would the solutions from here be good? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers Or is there something you require that those  can't  do?

Comment: From that page especially https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045/ might be interesting, it is easy with TikZ to make dashed lines as in the example in this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the answers linked to in the comments were written before `tikzmarknode` got added to the `tikzmark` library. With this addition, it is IMHO particularly straightforward to get something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[\mathrm{i}\int\!\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\bar\theta\,
\tikzmarknode[circle,draw,dashed,inner sep=2pt]{tc}{\dfrac{\theta\bar\theta}{\hbar}}
\left(L[\Phi]+\mathbb{J}\right)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could do much more with `tikzmarknode`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\tikzset{dashed circle/.style={circle,draw,dashed,inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{document}
The conventional \dots
\begin{equation}\label{eq:conventional}
 \mathcal{Z}[\mathbb{J}]=\exp\left[\mathrm{i}\int\!\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\bar\theta\,
 \tikzmarknode[dashed circle]{11}{1}
 \left(L[\Phi]+\mathbb{J}\right)\right]\;.
\end{equation}
The modified \dots
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{Z}'[\mathbb{J}]=\exp\left[\mathrm{i}\int\!\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\bar\theta\,
 \tikzmarknode[dashed circle]{tc1}{\dfrac{\theta\bar\theta}{\hbar}}
 \left(L[\Phi]+\mathbb{J}\right)\right]\;.\label{eq:Z'}
\end{equation}
\eqref{eq:conventional} except that $\tikzmarknode[dashed circle]{12}{1}$ got replaced by 
$\tikzmarknode[dashed circle]{tc2}{\dfrac{\theta\bar\theta}{\hbar}}$ in \eqref{eq:Z'}.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,latex-latex,thick] (tc1) to[bend left=10] (tc2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]