# using xkeyval for circling a number in a given color with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xkeyval

I've been trying all day to use xkeyval, but it seems like I just can't get the hook of it.

This is what I'm trying to do: I've got this number in a circle filled by a certain color.
The code for it is:

```
\newcommand*\circled[2]
    {\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
          {\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,fill=#2] (char)
          {\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}
```

I've taken this code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers). And just added the small modification which is the color it takes as a second argument.

I would like to be able to do that with xkeyval so I could use it that way:

```
\circled[fill=mycolor,char=mychar]
```

But I don't get how I could do this with xkeyval.

Is there a way?

Comment: why do you want to use xkeyval with tikz instead of the in-built pgfkeys?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I didn't know about pgfkeys!