# hyperlinking circled text

Tags: hyperlink

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045/38244), I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt, text width=5em] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{lipsum}        

\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \label{page1}.
\lipsum[1-20]

Now refer back to page \circled{\pageref*{page1}}
\end{document}
```

The following output is generated:

[image]

The hyperlink only points from the number (the red rectangle around it). What I need is the whole circle will be hyperlinked (so, clicking anywhere in the circle would work). Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt, text width=5em] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{lipsum}        

\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \label{page1}.
\lipsum[1-20]

Now refer back to page \hyperref[page1]{\circled{\pageref*{page1}}}
\end{document}
```