# Alternative to using nested tikz in reference-able markers

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing

based on [this nice question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) and its answers, I have this little code:

```latex
%
% circled steps (with labels to reference them!)
%
\newcommand*\circled[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,#1] (char) {#2};}}
\newcounter{cstepcnt}
\newcommand{\startcstep}{\setcounter{cstepcnt}{0}}
\newcommand{\cstep}{%
    \refstepcounter{cstepcnt}%
    \circled[red, font=\scriptsize]{\arabic{cstepcnt}}% this is pretty dangerous
}
```

This let me mark part of text, or equation, or whatever with small circled numbers that I can refer to later (with `\label` and `\ref`), like:

[image]

This in nice, and a better solution than used `\textcircled{}` (the numbers are badly centered, especially if they're bigger than 9, and there is no flexibility in the shape or colors), but I know this is living dangerously when I use it into a picture; sometime it works, some time it explodes (because, I know, you should never nest `tikzpictures`).

Is there a way to obtain the same flexibility? I mean, havinf a kind of "circled number steps" that I can use inside and outside tikzpictures?

This is a MWE, where all is working, because I was not able to find a simple example where it breaks... but it breaks sometime, giving very big or small circles.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\newcommand*\circled[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,#1] (char) {#2};}}
\newcounter{cstepcnt}
\newcommand{\startcstep}{\setcounter{cstepcnt}{0}}
\newcommand{\cstep}{%
    \refstepcounter{cstepcnt}%
    \circled[red, font=\scriptsize]{\arabic{cstepcnt}}% this is pretty dangerous
}
\renewcommand{\thecstepcnt}{\textbf{\arabic{cstepcnt}:}}
\begin{document}
one text here \cstep{} some text here \cstep\label{c:one}.

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[draw](A){text\cstep\label{c:inner}};
\end{tikzpicture}

And then ref~\ref{c:one} and \ref{c:inner}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK there is no really safe way of nesting `tikzpicture`s. Of course, you could make the above more likely to be stable by adding several keys like `minimum width=0pt,minimum height=0pt,minimum size=0pt` and so on, which may prevent them from growing too large. But still you will not be safe from some `every path/.append style=...`, nor `every node/.append style=...` unless you locally reset all those as well.

Comment: @marmot, thanks --- I suspected it. Maybe I should make the circle with some other graphic package... would be stable if I use the old `picture` one? Will investigate.

Comment: Aren't you the world expert in declaring new shapes? I suspect it would be much simpler to copy the `circle` node shape and make it much less susceptible to external directives. You could just look up the `ellipse` node shape from `pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex` and kick out all the adjustments. I do not see how then the size could be adjusted by some key, simply because you do no longer look at these keys. (This is also a conceivable way to find out what keys the shape looks at.)

Comment: @marmot thanks for the compliment, but I don't think so ;-)... anyway it's a good idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Revised version after your feedback.** This is an attempt of an answer but no guarantee that it works. Why should one not nest `tikzpicture`s? The main reason is that the pgf keys of the ambient `tikzpicture` will affect the shapes of the inner ones. One way to evade this is to create "new" shapes that merely differ from the standard ones by the `pgf` keys they use. So I copied the `ellipse` shape from `pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex`, dropped some pgf key and the inner sep sit now in the directory `Rmano` such that you can still change it from outside if needed. This shape is used at the pgf level. There is no mediator like the Ti*k*Z `\node` command which could obscure things. Unfortunately one has to work a bit harder to implement `baseline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{stubborn ellipse}
%
% Draws a circle around the text
%
{%
  \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
    \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }%
  \savedanchor\radius{%
    %
    % Calculate ``height radius''
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Rmano/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
    %
    % Calculate ``width radius''
    %
    \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/Rmano/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
    %
    % Adjust
    %
    \pgf@x=1.4142136\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=1.4142136\pgf@y%
  }%

  %
  % Anchors
  %
  \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}%
  \anchor{mid}{\centerpoint\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}}%
  \anchor{base}{\centerpoint\pgf@y=0pt}%
  \anchor{north}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{south}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{west}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa
  }%
  \anchor{mid west}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}
  }%
  \anchor{base west}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa%
    \pgf@y=0pt
  }%
  \anchor{north west}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{south west}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by-0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by-0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{east}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa
  }%
  \anchor{mid east}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}
  }%
  \anchor{base east}
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
    \pgf@y=0pt
  }%
  \anchor{north east}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchor{south east}
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\centerpoint}
    \advance\pgf@x by0.707107\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y by-0.707107\pgf@ya
  }%
  \anchorborder{
    \edef\pgf@marshal{%
      \noexpand\pgfpointborderellipse
      {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}
      {\noexpand\radius}%
    }%
    \pgf@marshal%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \centerpoint%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@ya%
  }%

  %
  % Background path
  %
  \backgroundpath
  {
    \pgf@process{\radius}%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgf@x%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgf@y%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xb%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by-\pgf@yb%
    \pgfpathellipse{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
  }%
}%
\pgfkeys{/Rmano/inner ysep/.initial=2pt,/Rmano/inner xsep/.initial=2pt}
%
\newcommand*\circled[2][]{\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
\pgf@xa=\ht0%
\advance\pgf@xa by \pgfkeysvalueof{/Rmano/inner ysep}%
\pgf@ya=0.4142136\pgf@xa%
\raisebox{-\pgf@ya}{\textcolor{red}{\begin{pgfpicture}%
\pgfnode{stubborn ellipse}{center}{#2}{#1}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}%
\end{pgfpicture}}}}
\makeatother
\newcounter{cstepcnt}
\newcommand{\startcstep}{\setcounter{cstepcnt}{0}}
\newcommand{\cstep}{%
    \refstepcounter{cstepcnt}%
    \typeout{\number\value{cstepcnt}}%
    \circled[cnode-\number\value{cstepcnt}]{\number\value{cstepcnt}}% this is pretty dangerous
}
\renewcommand{\thecstepcnt}{\textbf{\arabic{cstepcnt}:}}
\begin{document}
one text here \cstep{} some text here \cstep\label{c:one}.

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[draw](A){text\cstep\label{c:inner}};
\end{tikzpicture}

And then ref~\ref{c:one} and \ref{c:inner}.
\foreach \X in {1,...,12} {\cstep{}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Looking at this `\raisebox` hackery one can be really glad that Ti*k*Z comes with simple keys like `baseline` which allow one to avoid all this mess. ;-)

Comment: Version 2 works! Version 1 will explode, just try `\draw (0,0) node[draw, text width=5cm](A){text\cstep\label{c:inner}};` --- I think the problem is that in the `node` there is the `parttextbox` thing which is not really controllable (and I'd like it to be, sometime, to make magic like undo negative `xscale` or things like that. Thanks a lot! What about a minipackage? ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for letting me know! I see, text width enters twice, which makes perfect sense. (I guess it is not really nice enough to become a package on its own but may be useful for package authors.)

Comment: I posted a streamlined version for anyone interested!

Comment: Ok, it still will explode if you have a `baseline=4cm` in your external `tikzpicture`. I think it's not worthwhile to fight more...

Answer (score 1):

Really, it seems almost impossible to safely nest `pgfpictures` (as is clearly stated everywhere). So I implemented a different strategy that you can see in
this answer to the original question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496665/38080

## old answer: works sometime

Ok --- I simplified the wonderful @marmot answer ... here is a small package:

#### warning: it still explodes sometime (don't know why, no time to dig on). Definitely you should not nest `tikz` or `pgf` pictures...

```latex
% save as marmotcsteps.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{marmotcsteps}[2019/06/19 Circled steps that you can reference and use in and outside tikz v1]
\RequirePackage{tikz}
% invented by @marmot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496379/38080
% streamlined by @Rmano 

\pgfdeclareshape{stubborn ellipse}
% Draws a circle around the text
{%
  \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
    \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }%
  \savedanchor\radius{%
    % Calculate ``height radius''
    \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y by\pgf@yb%
    % Calculate ``width radius''
    \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xb%
    % Adjust so that it's a circle for 1-digit numbers
    \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@y\pgf@x=\pgf@y\fi
  }%
  % Anchors
  \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}%
  % Background path
  \backgroundpath
  {%
    \pgf@process{\radius}%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgf@x%
    \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgf@y%
    \pgfpathellipse{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand*\marmotcircled[1]{\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
    \pgf@ya=\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner ysep}%
    \raisebox{-\pgf@ya}{%
        \begin{pgfpicture}\pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/outer color}}%
            \pgfnode{stubborn ellipse}{center}{%
            \textcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/csteps/inner color}}{#1}}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}%
        \end{pgfpicture}%
    }}
\newcounter{cstepcnt}
\newcommand{\startcstep}{\setcounter{cstepcnt}{0}}
\newcommand{\cstep}{%
    \refstepcounter{cstepcnt}%
    \typeout{\number\value{cstepcnt}}%
    \marmotcircled{\number\value{cstepcnt}}% this is pretty dangerous
}
\renewcommand{\thecstepcnt}{\textbf{\arabic{cstepcnt}:}}
%
\pgfkeys{/csteps/inner ysep/.initial=1pt,
    /csteps/inner xsep/.initial=1pt,
    /csteps/inner color/.initial=red,
    /csteps/outer color/.initial=blue,
}
%
```

and you can use it as:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\usepackage{marmotcsteps}

\begin{document}
one text here \cstep{} some text here \cstep\label{c:one}.

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[draw, text width=5cm](A){text\cstep\label{c:inner}};
    \draw (4,0) node[draw, color=green](A){text\cstep\label{c:inner2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

And then \foreach \i in {0,...,12} {\cstep\ }

And then ref~\ref{c:one} and \ref{c:inner}.
\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: +1. One should always leave the package writing to those who know what they are doing. ;-)

Comment: @marmot --- thanks! I finally have a solution that works in _every_ case I checked, please look at it https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496665/38080