# How do I write this symbol in latex? (disjoint sharp operator)

Tags: symbols, math-operators, logic

I can't find this symbol used to indicate the disjoint sharp operator.

[image]

It's a # inside a circle. Is this symbol available in LaTex? if not, how can I draw it inside a mathematical equation?

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7045/31034

Comment: Here's two links that are helpful for this sort of problem in the future. I checked them and found nothing, but they're still useful for this sort of thing. http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html http://shapecatcher.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a scaled up version of `\bigcirc` and `\ooalign`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makecircled}[2][\mathord]{#1{\mathpalette\make@circled{#2}}}
\newcommand{\make@circled}[2]{%
  \begingroup\m@th
  \vphantom{\biggercirc{#1}}%
  \ooalign{$#1\biggercirc{#1}$\cr\hidewidth$#1#2$\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\biggercirc}[1]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.4}{$\m@th#1\bigcirc$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\disjointsharp}{\makecircled[\mathbin]{\#}}

\begin{document}

$A\disjointsharp B_{A\disjointsharp B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\mathbin` but it could be `\mathrel` depending on the meaning.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427 for a quick course on `\ooalign`.

With a smaller circle

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makecircled}[2][\mathord]{#1{\mathpalette\make@circled{#2}}}
\newcommand{\make@circled}[2]{%
  \begingroup\m@th
  \vphantom{\bigcirc}%
  \ooalign{$#1\bigcirc$\cr\hidewidth$#1\make@smaller{#1}{#2}$\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\make@smaller}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.7}{$\m@th#1#2$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\disjointsharp}{\makecircled[\mathbin]{\#}}

\begin{document}

$A\disjointsharp B_{A\disjointsharp B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

When symbols are “bigger”, they are usually centered with respect to the formula axis.

Another possibility:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makecircled}[2][\mathord]{#1{\mathpalette\make@circled{#2}}}
\newcommand{\make@circled}[2]{%
  \begingroup\m@th
  \sbox\z@{$#1A$}%
  \sbox\tw@{%
    \raisebox{\depth}{%
      \vphantom{$#1A$}%
      \ooalign{%
        \hidewidth$#1\make@smaller{#1}{#2}$\hidewidth\cr
        $#1\bigcirc$\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\z@}{\box\tw@}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\make@smaller}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.7}{$\m@th#1#2$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\disjointsharp}{\makecircled[\mathbin]{\#}}

\begin{document}

$A\disjointsharp B_{A\disjointsharp B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I copied your code and it is fine. The only thing I would change is the fact that the circle is bigget than A and B. How can I change its diameter?

Comment: @GerardoZinno In the image you showed the circle *is* larger than the letters.

Comment: I know. But is there a simple way to make the circle roughly the same size of the letters?

Comment: @GerardoZinno I added two new implementations

Answer (score 3):

I have created your symbol with a combination of packages. Excuse me for the complicated code. The symbol has the name `\disj`. It is a variable name that you can change. Here is my MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,scalerel}
\newcommand{\disj}{\mathrel{{\bigcircle}\mkern-4mu\raise.3ex\llap{$\scaleobj{.6}{\#}$}}}
\begin{document}
$A\disj B=C$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use TikZ to draw a circle node with a `#` inside. Using `\DeclareMathOperator` from `amsmath` improves the spacing. The character should be a bit smaller than the current font, which you can do using `\smaller` from the `relsize` package, to make sure it works in different fontsizes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{relsize}
\DeclareMathOperator{\chash}{\tikz{\node[circle,draw,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]{\smaller[3]\#}}}
\begin{document}
$A\chash B$

\Huge$A\chash B$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possibility with `stackengine` and the `\bigovoid` symbol from `mathabx` (without replacing the default maths fonts with the mathabx fonts):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{%
<-6> mathx5 
<6-7> mathx6 
<7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 
<9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 
<12-> mathx12
}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigovoid}{\mathop}{mathx}{"EC}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\Otag}{\mathbin{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\#}{\bigovoid}}}

\begin{document}

\[A \Otag B = C \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *Tante grazie*  for warning me, Sebastiano!

Comment: Ahahah. I'm very glad to help you and the correct behaviour user :0) excellent...tante grazie.