# How to suppress line separation in when using large (\circlearound) labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize, enumitem

I use itemize environments [based on textcircled numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers#7045), but unlike most applications I have multi-line paragraphs, and thus the "textcircling" creates a rather ugly line separation. Is there any way to suppress that?

I could think about two ways: either make tikz not do that, or somehow reversing the line sep manually (maybe enumitem provides a solution?), but couldn't find anything 'simple' yet.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[anchor=base,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=7pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[\circled{\textbf{1}}] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
 At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  

\item[\circled{\textbf{2}}]  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
 sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
 clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Paragraphs with unpleasant space after first line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! One of the many possible ways is to draw the circle in the `overlay` mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[2][]{\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[anchor=base,inner xsep=10pt] (char) {#2};
    \node[anchor=base,shape=circle,overlay,draw,inner sep=7pt,#1]
    {\phantom{#2}};}}   
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[{\circled[overlay]{\textbf{1}}}] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
 At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  

\item[{\circled[overlay]{\textbf{2}}}]  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
 sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
 clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That fixes the problem!