# How to format all cells in a given column of a tabular-like environment

Tags: tables, formatting, columns

Suppose I have a command `\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{...}`. In particular this :[Good way to circle text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496665/209459)

Now I want to do some thing like this :

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|c}
Some long piece of text & \mycommand{Something}\\
Some long piece of text & \mycommand{Something}\\
Some long piece of text & \mycommand{Something}
\end{tabularx}
```

How do I do this without having to type `\mycommand{...}` for all cells in that column.

I have found `>{...}` for font styles and alignment but I don't know if something like this can be done.

EDIT : I would also like to know if `\mycommand` can have multiple arguments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question doesn't appear to be related to the `tabularx` package *per se*. It could pertain to *any* column type, in `tabular`, `tabular*`, and many other tabular-like environments, right? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes any. I need my actual document like that.

Comment: Please edit the title and body of your query to focus on what is actually required.

Comment: You still have a reference to `tabularx` in the title of your posting, and `\begin{tabularx}{X|c}` is bound to generate a syntax error since the all-important desired-width argument is missing. (Did you mean to write `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|c}`?) The more extraneous stuff is eliminated, the easier it will be for readers to focus on what's relevant.

Comment: You can see the `collcell` package.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide some easy examples. I don't know much about latex macros. @Bernard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo with the `\Circled` command (from `circledsteps)`, using the `collcell` package: T, defined a new `C` column type, which collects the contents of each cell of the column, andexcutes the `\Circled` macro on this contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = footnotesize}
\usepackage{circledsteps} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\Circled}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|C}
Some long piece of text & Something \\
Some very long piece of text & Something \\
Some still quite longer piece of text & Something
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]