# Is there any way to increase the line thickness of the circles when using the 'circledsteps' package?

Tags: line, circles

Is there any way to increase the **line thickness** of the circles when using the [circledsteps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) package?

@leandriis Thank you for your response using **\thicklines** and **\linethickness{}**.

Apologies for not being initially specific, but is there a way to **globally** set the line thickness for *ALL* occurrences of \Circled{} to **\thicklines** without having to preface *EACH* occurrence of \Circled{} ?

According to the answer provided below, the line thickness for \Circled{} can be adjusted by placing \thicklines and/or \linethickness{} in the preamble.

Update: After placing \linethickness{2pt} in the preamble, the \Circled{} line thickness increased globally, and placing \thicklines in the preamble increased the line thickness globally, presumably from 0.4pt to 0.8pt.

After increasing the line thickness with \linethickness{2pt}, a cursory check indicated the line thickness change did NOT appear to affect the line thickness elsewhere in the compiled file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`circledsteps` seems to internally use `picture` to draw the circle/oval shape. To increase the line thickness inside of a `picture`, you can use `\thicklines`. This will increase the line thickness from the default value of `0.4pt` to  `0.8pt`. If you want to increase the thickness to an arbitrary value of your choice instead, you could alternatively use `\linethickness{2pt}` or any other value of your choice.

Depending on where you place these commands, the effect will be global for the whole document of just local to a single/few cicled numbers. Be aware thought, that using `\thicklines` in the preamble will not only change the line thickness of all circled numbers throughout the document but will also influence the line thickness of all `picture` environments inside the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\begin{document}

circled numbers, regular line width: \Circled{1} \Circled{100}.

{\thicklines
circled numbers, increased line width: \Circled{1} \Circled{100}.}


circled numbers, regular line width: \Circled{1} \Circled{100}.

{\linethickness{2pt}
circled numbers, increased line width: \Circled{1} \Circled{100}.}


circled numbers, regular line width: \Circled{1} \Circled{100}.


\end{document}
```