# Miscellaneous symbols from music textbook

Tags: symbols, characters

I am totally new to LaTeX (using overleaf), but I have a handle on the form of the document I want to create--just missing a couple pieces, which include the special characters I need to replicate from a music theory textbook.

Specifically,  I am trying to use [these special characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSbom.jpg)

I consulted [this article](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), but it is 348 pages long, and I figured I would ask the community before scanning the whole document.  Moreover, I will need a pointer as to which packages to load so that I can use the special characters I am looking for.

Thank you in advance for the help!

[Additional symbol needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTpgJ.jpg)

Comment: The circled numbers/text can be done programmatically. For everything else: if it is musical notation I would check the section about lilypond glyphs in the symbol list; but I doubt you will find them there. The easiest is to create an image of the symbol and load them using `\includegraphics`. // For creating the image, if you use something like IPE then you can export into EPS format.

Comment: For circled numbers, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers

Comment: You might find them in a Unicode font that you can use in LuaTeX or XeTeX. I don’t know for sure, though.

Comment: @Davislor do you know how I can view the characters/symbols available in the packages you mention?  I found that one of the symbols is called an "ominus".  I am not sure how to include it.  I am unsure about how to find the others.

Answer (score 3):

With `l3draw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw,graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\symA}{}
 {
  \makebox[ \dim_eval:n { \width+0.05ex } ]
   {
    \draw_begin:
    \draw_cap_round:
    \draw_linewidth:n { 0.12ex }
    \draw_path_circle:nn { 0.5ex, 0.5ex } { 0.5ex }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    \draw_path_moveto:n { -0.2ex, 0.5ex }
    \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.2ex, 0.5ex }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    \draw_end:
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\symB}{}
 {
  \makebox[ \dim_eval:n { \width+0.05ex } ]
   {
    \draw_begin:
    \draw_cap_round:
    \draw_linewidth:n { 0.12ex }
    \draw_path_circle:nn { 0.5ex, 0.5ex } { 0.5ex }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.5ex, 0.5ex }
    \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.5ex, 1.5ex }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.5ex, 1.55ex }
    \draw_path_arc:nnn { 240 } { 300 } { 0.5ex }
    \draw_path_arc:nnn { -40 } { -90 } { 0.6ex }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    \draw_end:
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\symC}{}
 {
  \raisebox{1ex}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{\symB}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

First \symA{} second \symB{} third \symC{} and so on

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow--thank you @egreg.  question--how did you know specifically how to program these?  Would you be able to do the same for the other symbols (i'll be adding an additional symbol I just ran into as well)

Comment: @286642 The additional symbol seems `\textsf{\.{F}}`

Comment: Thank you!  Still missing some from the images I posted, but at least I have a  start

Comment: So I was finally able to try this code out, but it's not working for me--i'm getting "first       second      third       " but nothing in the spaces.  Please advise

Comment: in response to your code for \textsf{\.{F}} . . . Overleaf did not seem to like the 
"\." combination