# \textcircled in newpxtext do not work with ctex

Tags: text, ctex

\textcircled in newpxtext do not work with ctex

in newpx documentation, it says:

[image]

if I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{ctex}
\begin{document}
\textcircled{X}\textcircled{2}
\end{document}
```

it is correct, but **if I add `\usepackage{ctex}` and it will look like this:**

[image]

Comment: Try loading ctex before newpxtext

Comment: You may also want to consider the [circledtext](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circledtext) package. It offers many options for customization.

Comment: Thanks! ctex before newpxtext and `\documentclass{ctexart}` both work. Another package is hyperref which also redefine `\textcircled` and it should be loaded before newpxtext

Comment: hyperref doesn't redefine \textcircled, it only adds a PU-variant. And if you load hyperref before newpttext, the later will destroy the command in the bookmarks. See a similar question about newtxtext: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659543/2388