# Encircle text in LaTeX

Tags: packages, text

I'm wondering if there is a command which allows me to encircle text like that:

[image]

It is important that the line space does not change.

Comment: So, the encircled text is supposed to be printed inline with other text surrouding it?

Comment: Hello @JasperHabicht yes as a normal text

Comment: Should the text inside the ellipse be as large as the surrounding text? Because it will be hard to do this without enlarging the line space or having the ellipsis overlap the line above and/or below. Maybe have a look at the `circledsteps` package.

Comment: Hi @JasperHabicht the package you suggested is perfect. The only side effect is the line space, ut it's ok.

Comment: Related: [Good way to make `\textcircled` numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

another option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{circledsteps}

\begin{document}
    text text text  
    \Circled[outer color=blue,inner color=blue,fill color=lime]{texto}         
     text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text text text
\end{document}
```

[image]

[Circledsteps manual](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/circledsteps/circledsteps-manual.pdf)

if you set `\tikzset{/csteps/inner ysep=20pt}` you will have

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe for inline text you will prefer a stadium shape (rectangle with rounded corners) to avoid the dilema of increase the interline space vs overlapping text when the encircled text is too wide.

A easy way to do this is a `\tcbox` (`tcolorbox` package) with the `on line` option, with the bonus that it is highly customizable:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\myoval}{on line,arc=7pt,colback=yellow!50,colframe=orange!50,
boxrule=1pt, boxsep=1pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-6] 
\lipsum[1][1] Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,\myoval{adipiscing vitae}, felis 
\lipsum[1][3-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Fran thank you very much for your solution

Answer (score 3):

This uses tikz to overlap the ellipse and the surreounding space, but not the text itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\ellipted}[1]{% #1 = text
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) {#1};
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \node[draw, red, ellipse, inner sep=1pt, fit=(A)] {};
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
This is a line of text.\\
This is a line of text.\\
This is \ellipted{a line} of text.\\
This is a line of text.\\
This is a line of text.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

You asked to encircle text and showed an image not of a circle but of an oval (perhaps, even an ellipse; I cannot tell).  If you wish to literally ***encircle*** stuff, i.e, surround it by a circle, consider using `\textcircled` (but cf. [issue 926](http://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/926)) for single letters and, say, TikZ (thx to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660525) otherwise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\encircle}[1]{% #1 = text; thx to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660525
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) {#1};
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \node[draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, fit=(A)] {};
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}\noindent
I like to move it move it.\\
\textcircled{I} like to move it move it.\\
I like to move it move it.\\
Ya like to \encircle{move it!}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `tikzmark`. Define a command `\encircle` that takes two arguments, one optional.

```
\encircle[<tikz options>]{<text>}
```

The optional first argument can include color, line width, changing `inner xsep` or `inner ysep`, etc.

[image]

Here is the code. You must compile twice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes.geometric, fit}

\newcommand{\encircle}[2][]{\tikzmarknode{A}{#2}\tikz[remember picture, overlay]
    {\node[draw, ellipse, inner xsep=-.4em, inner ysep=3pt, fit=(A),#1]{};}}

\begin{document}

Here are a few lines of text. Here are a few lines of text. Here are a few lines of text. 
Here are a few lines of text. Here are a few lines of text. Here are a few lines of text. 
I want to circle \encircle[red, thick]{some text} in the middle without affecting line spacing.
Here are a few lines of text. Here are a few lines of text. Here are a few lines of text. 
Here are a few lines of text. Here are a few lines of text.

\end{document}
```