# Circling a number on a number line with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I would like to create a command that allows me to create a number line and circle two given values.

[image]

I have the code for the number line:

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\NL}[2]{\begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =
1.07] \draw[latex-latex] (#1-0.5,0) -- (#2+0.5,0) ;  \foreach \x in  {#1,...,#2}  \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt); \foreach \x in {#1,...,#2}  \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below]  {$\x$}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{center}}

\begin{document} \NLTwo{1}{10}

\end{document}
```

And this code makes nice looking circles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{1} \circled{2} \circled{3} end.
\end{document}
```

...and I'm hopeful these ideas can be combined.

For example, I would like to use a command like \NLTwo{1}{10}{3}{5} that produces a number line with numbers from 1 to 10 (inputs 1 and 2) and circles numbers 3 and 5 (inputs 3 and 4) looking something like

[image]

Thanks so much, Wendy

Comment: You can try this [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660482/encircle-text-in-latex/660534#660534](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660482/encircle-text-in-latex/660534#660534)

Comment: Your first example won't compile because you've defined `\NL` but use `\NLTwo`. Note that the use of `scale=1.07` is probably a Bad Idea, typographically speaking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vanilla solution:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex] (-1,0)--(10.5,0);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}
        \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below] () {\small \x};
        \node[below,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] at (3,-.1) {3};
        \node[below,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] at (5,-.1) {5};
    \end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, adding the code \node[below,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] at (3,-.1) {3}; below my NL code works really well!

Comment: I am not quite advanced enough to move beyond vanilla, but greatly appreciate your effort. One day I hope to progress!

Comment: @WendyTaylor You are wellcomed . My 'vanilla' code works to solve Your problem.

Comment: Here's the code I ended up going with. 

\newcommand{\NLTwo}[4]{\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.07]
\draw[latex-latex] (#1-0.5,0) -- (#2+0.5,0) ; 
\foreach \x in  {#1,...,#2} 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {#1,...,#2} 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\node[below,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=9pt] at (#3,-.01) {};
\node[below,shape=circle,draw,inner sep=9pt] at (#4,-.01) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}}

Comment: I specified the circles to be larger so I didn't need to repeat the number (removing the shaddow) and I've made the circles large enough to work with two digit numbers. Thanks again @raffaele santor

Answer (score 9):

Although you could use the syntax you suggested, I'd use `pgfkeys` and a key-value interface. That's easier to extend and keep track of. I also make the argument to `\NL` optional. Without an optional argument, a simple numberline from 1 to 10 is drawn with nothing circled. With an optional argument, the `start` `end` and `circle` numbers can be specified, as well as regular pgf/tikz options.

For example,

```
\NL
  
\NL[circle={3,5}]

\NL[every node/.append style={fill=blue!25!black!5},circle={2,4,6,8},start=-1,end=12,thick,draw=blue!25!black,text=blue!25!black]
```

produces three number lines with increasing degrees of customisation.

[image: three number lines]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711912/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Wendy Taylor: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/711907/
\tikzset{%
  numberline/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  numberline/.cd,
  start/.store in=\numberlinestart,
  end/.store in=\numberlineend,
  circle/.store in=\numberlinecircle,
  start=1,
  end=10,
  circle={},
}

\NewDocumentCommand \NL { O{} }
{%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.07cm,y=1.07cm,numberline/.cd,#1]
      \draw [Latex-Latex] (\numberlinestart-0.5,0pt) -- (\numberlineend+0.5,0pt);
      \foreach \i in {\numberlinestart,...,\numberlineend} 
      \draw (\i,3pt) -- (\i,-3pt) node (n-\i) [below] {$\i$}; 
      \foreach \i in \numberlinecircle 
      \node [circle,draw,inner sep=1.5pt] at (n-\i) {\phantom{$\i$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}%
}


\begin{document}

\NL
  
\NL[circle={3,5}]

\NL[every node/.append style={fill=blue!25!black!5},circle={2,4,6,8},start=-1,end=12,thick,draw=blue!25!black,text=blue!25!black]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

A solution of another flavor; Just by cleaning the code, I added an additional variable to, after drawing the arrow, do its style as required for each requested number within the range, of course.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand{\NL}[3]{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1.07]
            \draw[latex-latex](#1-0.5,0) -- (#2+0.5,0);
            \foreach \x in  {#1,...,#2}{
                \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] (N-\x) {$\x$};
            }
            \foreach \y/\z in  {#3}{
                \node[draw=\z,circle,minimum size=13pt] at (N-\y.center){};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}}
\begin{document}
    Numbers aligned with the text:  \circled{2} \circled{4} \circled{6} \circled{9} end.
    \NL{1}{10}{2/red,4/blue,6/orange,9/green!50!black}
    
    Another result:
    \NL{-3}{7}{-2/red,0/blue,4/orange,7/green!50!black}
    
\end{document}
```